# Ex-Increasing Set Sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence

## Background

An **ex-increasing set sequence** of order \$N\$ is defined as a sequence of integer sets \$S_1,S_2,\cdots,S_n\$ which satisfies the following:

- Each \$S_i\$ is a non-empty subset of \$\{1,2,\cdots,N\}\$.
- For \$1\le i<n\$, \$S_i \cap S_{i+1} = \varnothing\$, i.e. any two consecutive sets have no elements in common.
- For \$1\le i<n\$, the mean (average value) of \$S_i\$ is strictly less than that of \$S_{i+1}\$.

## Challenge

Given a positive integer `N`, output the length of the longest ex-increasing set sequence of order `N`.

## Test cases

These are based on [the results by Project Euler user **thundre**](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3605#p39060).

```
1 => 1 // {1}
2 => 2 // {1} {2}
3 => 3 // {1} {2} {3}
4 => 5 // {1} {2} {1,4} {3} {4}
5 => 7 // {1} {2} {1,4} {3} {2,5} {4} {5}
6 => 10 // {1} {2} {1,4} {3} {1,4,5} {2,3,6} {4} {3,6} {5} {6}
7 => 15 // {1} {2} {1,4} {3} {1,2,7} {3,4} {1,2,5,7} {4} {1,3,6,7} {4,5} {1,6,7} {5} {4,7} {6} {7}
8 => 21
9 => 29
10 => 39
11 => 49
12 => 63
13 => 79
14 => 99
15 => 121
16 => 145
17 => 171
18 => 203
19 => 237
20 => 277
21 => 321
22 => 369
23 => 419
24 => 477
25 => 537
```

### Rules

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest valid submission in bytes wins.

## Bounty

This problem has been discussed [here on Project Euler forum](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3605) about 4 years ago, but we failed to come up with a provable polynomial-time algorithm (in terms of `N`). Therefore, I will award +200 bounty to the first submission that achieves this, or prove its impossibility.

Comment: I've spent over a week trying to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm or an NP-hardness proof using a reduction. Has anyone here made any progress on this?

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 28 bytes

```
⟦₁⊇ᶠk⊇pSs₂ᶠ{c≠&⟨+/l⟩ᵐ<ᵈ}ᵐ∧Sl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aGh91tT/ctiAbSBUEFz9qagJyqpMfdS5QezR/hbZ@zqP5Kx9unWDzcGtHLZB@1LE8OOf/f@P/UQA)

This is really damn slow. Takes about 30 seconds for `N = 3`, and it didn't complete after 12 minutes for `N = 4`.

#### Explanation

```
⟦₁                             Take the range [1, …, Input]
  ⊇ᶠk                          Find all ordered subsets of that range, minus the empty set
     ⊇                         Take an ordered subset of these subsets
      pS                       Take a permutation of that subset and call it S
       Ss₂ᶠ                    Find all substrings of 2 consecutive elements in S
           {           }ᵐ      Map for each of these substrings:
            c≠                   All elements from both sets must be different
              &⟨+/l⟩ᵐ            And the average of both sets (⟨xyz⟩ is a fork like in APL)
                     <ᵈ          Must be in strictly increasing order
                         ∧Sl   If all of this succeeds, the output is the length of L.
```

#### Faster version, 39 bytes

```
⟦₁⊇ᶠk⊇{⟨+/l⟩/₁/₁}ᵒSs₂ᶠ{c≠&⟨+/l⟩ᵐ<₁}ᵐ∧Sl
```

This takes about 50 seconds on my computer for `N = 4`.

This is the same program except we sort the subset of subsets by average instead of taking a random permutation. So we use `{⟨+/l⟩/₁/₁}ᵒ` instead of `p`.

```
{         }ᵒ     Order by:
 ⟨+/l⟩             Average (fork of sum-divide-length)
      /₁/₁         Invert the average twice; this is used to get a float average
```

We need to get a float average because I just discovered a ridiculous bug in which floats and integers don't compare by value but by type with ordering predicates (this is also why I use `<ᵈ` and not `<₁` to compare both averages; the latter would require that double inversion trick to work).

Comment: I was planning to slowly work my way up to tackling this one (since @JonathanAllan mentioned it in the other comment), but I'm probably weeks behind coming up with anything like this! I like how (like most Brachylog answers) in the end it just looks like a neat restatement of the question itself.

Comment: @sundar you can always come back to it later and try to rediscover a solution!

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (81 bytes)

```
{YY@#(#{{2bW%ee{)*~}%}:Z~{)Z__1b\,d/\a+}%$}%{_,1>{2ew{z~~&!\~=>}%0&!}{,}?},:,:e>}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7BYY%40%23(%23%7B%7B2bW%25ee%7B)*~%7D%25%7D%3AZ~%7B)Z__1b%5C%2Cd%2F%5Ca%2B%7D%25%24%7D%25%7B_%2C1%3E%7B2ew%7Bz~~%26!%5C~%3D%3E%7D%250%26!%7D%7B%2C%7D%3F%7D%2C%3A%2C%3Ae%3E%7D%0A%0A3%5C~). It should execute for input `4` in a reasonable time, but I wouldn't try it with higher inputs.

#### Dissection

```
{                 e# Declare a block (anonymous function)
  YY@#(#          e# There are 2^N subsets of [0, N), but the empty subset is problematic
                  e# so we calculate 2^(2^N - 1) subsets of the non-empty subsets
  {               e# Map integer to subset of non-empty subsets:
    {             e#   Define a block to map an bitset to its set indices; e.g. 9 => [0 3]
      2bW%ee      e#     Convert to base 2, reverse, and index
      {)*~}%      e#     If the bit was set, keep the index
    }:Z           e#   Assign the block to variable Z
    ~             e#   Evaluate it
    {             e#   Map those indices to non-empty subsets of [0, N):
      )Z          e#     Increment (to skip the empty set) and apply Z
      __1b\,d/    e#     Sum one copy, take length of another, divide for average
      \a+         e#     Wrap the subset and prepend its average value
    }%
    $             e#   Sort (lexicographically, so by average value)
  }%
  {               e# Filter out subsets of subsets with conflicts:
    _,1>{         e#   If the length is greater than 1
      2ew         e#     Take each consecutive pair of subsets
      {           e#     Map:
        z~        e#       Zip and expand to get [score1 score2] [subset1 subset2]
        ~&!\      e#       No element in common => 1
        ~=        e#       Different scores => 0
        >         e#       1 iff both constraints are met
      }%
      0&!         e#     1 iff no consecutive pair failed the test
    }{
      ,           e#   Otherwise filter to those of length 1
    }?
  },
  :,:e>           e# Map to size of subset and take the greatest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 175 bytes

A naive and rather slow recursive search. Takes about 15 seconds to compute the 7 first terms on TIO.

```javascript
n=>(a=[...Array(n)].reduce(a=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[x,...y],x=n--)],[[]]),g=(p,b=a,n)=>a.map(a=>(m=a.map(n=>s+=++k*b.includes(n)?g:n,s=k=0)&&s/k)>p&&g(m,a,-~n),r=r>n?r:n))(r=0)|r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LboQwDEX38xVZobgxaburpnVG/Q6URQYCmgIOcjrVoD5@nQbNxvY9utb5CF8ht3JZPmtOXdx62picDtRYa99FwqoZvJXYXdtYsNt5wH3YOSx6LeS2x9XjjbiuwWPTeA84kF7wTAEZyN3L5V3PdL@LJRsyZnw42wu307WLuahOw5Ex00hPUFX5cQS3VNWgZwxY/zGgkDg@yZEBtJTSj2x9Es2K1POrYvWmXsoyBtT3Qak2cU5TtFMaNKPqiwAOv9s/)

or [test this modified version](https://tio.run/##JU67bsMwDNzzFZocqqLVdiuc0oHXDC2QjoYGxS@4tmlDSoIYRfvrrpwsPN6Bd8dve7W@cO10jnksq6WmhSkFS7nWOnPOzsDSaFeVl6IKcrrqFtehBzvBHJTbSmeDN@I4lgbz3BiJDcGEJ7LImFFuJKUPR8iAgR57qPKKlOqeTrrlor@UlQ99@yZh9NTRi4wi/9zJdIqiBga0GP8x3l9DGzocuZT3LoEjZchSSnB3z3GpRwcsSLzuBIt38RZAKSl@NkIUI/uxr3Q/NuFEiW0itgEOX58f2p9dy01bz1DDmrf5Xf4B) that outputs the longest ex-increasing set sequence.

#### How?

We first compute the powerset of \$\{1,2,\dots,n\}\$ and store it in \$a\$:

```javascript
a = [...Array(n)].reduce(a =>
  [...a, ...a.map(y => [x, ...y], x = n--)],
  [[]]
)
```

Recursive part:

```javascript
g = (                         // g = recursive function taking:
  p,                          //   p = previous mean average
  b = a,                      //   b = previous set
  n                           //   n = sequence length
) =>                          //
  a.map(a =>                  // for each set a[] in a[]:
    (m = a.map(n =>           //   for each value n in a[]:
      s +=                    //     update s:
        ++k * b.includes(n) ? //       increment k; if n exists in b[]:
          g                   //         invalidate the result (string / integer --> NaN)
        :                     //       else:
          n,                  //         add n to s
      s = k = 0)              //     start with s = k = 0; end of inner map()
      && s / k                //   m = s / k = new mean average
    ) > p                     //   if it's greater than the previous one,
    && g(m, a, -~n),          //   do a recursive call with (m, a, n + 1)
    r = r > n ? r : n         //   keep track of the greatest length in r = max(r, n)
  )                           // end of outer map()
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>205</s> <s>197</s> <s>184</s> 182 bytes

- Saved <s>eight</s> twenty-one bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).
- Saved two bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```python
f=lambda N,c=[[1]]:max([len(c)]+[f(N,c+[n])for k in range(N)for n in combinations(range(1,N+1),k+1)if not{*c[-1]}&{*n}and sum(c[-1])/len(c[-1])<sum(n)/len(n)]);from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc1NDoIwEAXgq8zKTAFjGjdG5QpcoOmi/FQb6QwpNdEQzo5Q4ixeJt9bvOEbn0znZbFlb3zdGqiKplRKan315oOq7wgboXNlcW1yRVpYDvACRxAMPTqsEtAGDfvakYmOacS9lUWVS1G81nAWiOOUNeoo9XyYMpoNtTC@PSYSpzSW3vumtAsJLW42sAcXuxCZ@xGcHzjEbBmCo4i9GyN6M6At4D8LF7He8gM)

Comment: [197 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwEER/JSfZbSNSvIjaX/AHlj3E2miw2S1pBEX89moriHMa3gwz/SNfVNbj6OvOxePJmYNtaqKKeRvdHahrBRrkkjx8kpKE0WsyYoKY4RaBqGg0HoO4HFQGSE7OLVT2UFZor8hT@TqV/wO2xBi8Ec3PoqFlxa/Fs5CXk9M8OiNczd@z3U9UvkSQceeTRhNym7JqN5gQe025GPsUJEMXhgzR9eDt79Zs8KPxDQ) using `sum` instead of `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thank you.