# Get the century of a year

Tags: code-golf

Your program has to have an year like `1957` to be the input and then output the century of that year.

For example:

```
In: 1946
Out: 20
In: 1705
Out: 18
In: 1900
Out: 19
In: 100
Out: 1
In: 2001
Out 21
```

because 1946 is in the 20th century.

Keep in mind that 2000 should be 20th century or 1900 should be in 19th century.

**Therefore, the first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.**

Any programming language is allowed and **keep your code short and sweet. :)**

**Additional Challenge: Try to also include float values**

Comment: "Try to also include float values" Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: @wastl Maybe OP means `Century = Year/100 + 1` without rounding... But that means that 2000 and 1900 etc. would be 21st and 20th century respectively

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Probably because it is trivial.

Comment: Since when we are downvoting trivial challenges?

Comment: @DeadPossum I downvoted because this challenge is neither interesting nor golf-able. There is no algorithmic complexity in finding the century: nearly all answers simply implement the expression `floor((year - 1)/100) + 1`, and there aren't other clever optimizations that can be done to shorten the overall program; there aren't any "alternative approaches" to the challenge. Since most answers implement the exact same expression, this challenge looks no more interesting than a list of "floor," "decrement," "divide," and "increment" functions in various languages.

Comment: How far in the future must our answers be correct until? Is it acceptable to only produce correct input up to the present year? (It matters in the R answer, we can save 2 bytes by only being correct up to the year 9998, possibly 9999)

Comment: Real programmers enumerate their centuries starting from zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <strike>4</strike>  3 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Jonathon Allan

```
т/î
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YpP@4XX//xsZGBgAAA)

Comment: I like the extra spaces around the `4` so that the crossed-out 4 is no longer a 4.

Answer (score 34):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), <strike>308</strike> 298 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE x
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS x
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
GET TO THE CHOPPER x
HERE IS MY INVITATION x
GET UP 99
HE HAD TO SPLIT 100
ENOUGH TALK
TALK TO THE HAND x
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY8xT8QwDIX3/Iq3sfYkBjr6ruZiXZOU2Lmq4wlGBBIT/744hxBLFD1/ef5y@/r4fH973XexB4XGspokDpE3nGIVtUQKq8z4DltpUDY0RVswhLPfPasgdaYgUVXHpgIx5LIGwUrZ@oj00lEQji2fIsozXhqrSckKyhP@0UhXhkVOnuvKlX2YEk9CxvN2X@qUAy5YloWrr4yOQRRpg@SrGPVizzvsquPohBdP/aUus@sdhiFwLu0cYTRfQj/@emMX@v3uXebInGFck2R3mPb9MD49/gA)

This seemed a challenge easy enough to try to write my first answer in ArnoldC...

Comment: Upvote cause it's ArnoldC

Comment: Please vote on the solution, *not* the language.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, 14 bytes

```
y=>1+--y/100|0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/S1s5QW1e3Ut/QwKDG4H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqGlhYWmTpqGkYGBgabmfwA)

Answer (score 10):

## Vim, 13 bytes

```
3I0<Esc>$3hd0<C-x>xx<C-a>
```

Comment: [Shorter version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207805)

Answer (score 10):

## Taxi, <strike>1327/2433</strike> 1057/1835 bytes

Two versions here; the shortest one works but shows the result in decimal format (e.g. `20.000000` instead of `20`). I am posting both because, while the longer version is more correct, I still hope to win this code golf with the short one (it could require a little bit of tweaking, though).

**Short version**

[You can test it here.](https://tio.run/##rZPBboMwDIbvPIUfYEK0O7W3bpN665C2F/CIIVFp0jlhbE/PUi0gCowxqRcUnOT//Du2w0/VNHsDzkBqrIPnPFcZbaEm6@5g5SMl5WHFqpC9YBylKjtWZ0A4o7WkC2IojNLFRe1VEjzgG5W5spL4K45@KMP4DGoesBNCOWU07MqSOvkXh5xJVQo4VCdiU5rCIwjHiOFqrUWwtdmAslCjl/codJOicbRKkkXn/mNi7uwBmU0NKTrpP3xsLV9rjM1ejIWnu2fRf8UFVX5SH0oQoNd4NPq9Im6xw3S2oA07OdkqN8CNd/pOA6@z@kdvcqWPxLbryfA/oTio2C37fsRaWKPenLbiV6M71exBNqTihx72yFjQL1kMLzbNOkmS5hs)

```
Go to Post Office: west, 1st left, 1st right, 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: west, 1st left, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Starchild Numerology: east, 1st left, 1st left, 1st left, 2nd left.
99 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
100 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Addition Alley: east, 1st left, 2nd right, 3rd right, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Narrow Path Park: north, 1st right, 1st left, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Divide and Conquer: east, 1st right, 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Go to Trunkers: east, 1st right, 3rd right, 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: east, 1st right, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: east, 1st left, 1st right.
Go to Taxi Garage: east, 1st right, 1st left, 1st right.
```

**Long version**

[You can test it here.](https://tio.run/##rVU7b9swEN79Kw5ashSC3QAFnM21gQwJUgMu0KHwwEgn6WCFpx6puvn1KlU9LEuKYhdZDJEmv8fxO9KqP1QU9wyWYcvGwrcoogDv4IjGfoKFm0kxqr@E4qQz6c@2FBzyDBRkyhjUMQrETDou0b4nCF/VM6YRmQTl1Z9VLP35CappglUYkiXWsEpTbOF3VkmQUBrCU/6CwinHjgLVkKL/9VmHta3lEsjAUTl4R6XsKKg/W8znF627xsTU2iclwkfYKpu4Hzk0ls8xhmZLY/XR3UrYPcULqryh3xQiKIexZv0rR2lo@3LuQLPYZDQqH0A3/KfrtOZrrb6TTcn1AcW0mazHI4i9in1k7gdcF9ZonXAGu/yU@XaiwfzijuQq0Q@sH5S9cQX5mQkHaMyGYrJmPy3kNUhZYyujGp7loDr8sojvi1gLvSA8qucG8IeQRbkxsMGMbXVR@DPP93ptd77uSpJ2YipO3dthdyQbJOXWLFUaPM12tXatrp2syHkHV4OOwOGGTEhbz5W63bnvV/B0JQ4a6cKIn060gm7Gjcuetf9A7KRuvPFrzKH9TsC8f4lz9diP6pxW1HmwGlFnb5jhvJQ12sJ1U7rnD@6VqBjf6Mf@7VUUi@V8XvwF):

```
Go to Post Office: west, 1st left, 1st right, 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: west, 1st left, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Starchild Numerology: east, 1st left, 1st left, 1st left, 2nd left.
99 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
100 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Addition Alley: east, 1st left, 2nd right, 3rd right, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Narrow Path Park: north, 1st right, 1st left, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Go to Divide and Conquer: east, 1st right, 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Go to Trunkers: east, 1st right, 3rd right, 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: east, 1st right, 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey: east, 6th right, 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.
[processDigits]
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: north, 1st left, 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
Go to Writer's Depot: west.
"." is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
Go to Crime Lab: east, 1st right, 2nd right, 2nd left.
Switch to plan "notAColon" if no one is waiting.
Switch to plan "print".
[notAColon]
Go to Cyclone: west, 1st right, 1st left, 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.
Go to KonKat's: east, 2nd right, 2nd right.
Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.
Go to Chop Suey: north, 1st right, 1st right.
Switch to plan "processDigits".
[print]
Go to KonKat's: east.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: south, 3rd right, 1st left.
Go to Taxi Garage: east, 1st right, 1st left, 1st right.
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
/₁₀₀⌉₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/9RU@OjpgYQ6ukEsv//NzIwMPgfBQA)

Just wanted to try my hand at Brachylog. Uses the "divide by 100 and ceil the result" method that many other answers use.

Comment: Now that you are a Brachylog expert :p maybe try [Ex-Increasing Set Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/169040/53748), it might be quite good for that :)

Comment: It's been a while since I saw a Brachylog answer not posted by me :p

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```r
1+scan()%/%99.99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31C7ODkxT0NTVV/V0lLP0vK/kYGB4X8A)

Saved 1 byte thanks to digEmAll!
-2 bytes thanks to JDL!

Comment: Not completely sure... does this work too `1+(scan()-1)%/%100` (18 bytes) or I'm missing something ?

Comment: @digEmAll Nice! Seems to work fine.

Comment: the challenge doesn't say how far in the future we need to go but `1+scan()%/%99.99` may save 2 bytes (it will start to go wonky after 100 centuries)

Answer (score 6):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
@)OuI('d,U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/99B07/UU0M9RSf0/39DSwNDAA)

This wraps onto the cube as follows

```
    @ )
    O u
I ( ' d , U . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgKQogICAgTyB1CkkgKCAnIGQgLCBVIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=MTk0Ngo=&speed=20)

Not sure what I was thinking when I did the first one.

Excluding the path changes the general process is `I('d,)O@` - Input integer, decrement, push 100, integer divide, increment, output integer and exit.

***Float version 16 bytes***

And since it was an interesting exercise, here's a version that will handle a float input.  Try 1900, 1900.0 and 1900.1.  Of course it isn't really doing floats as Cubix prefers integers and the format of the float doesn't really matter. 1900 1, 1900-1 and 1900.1 are all treated the same.

```
WBiWIUd'.(B?@,)O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z/cKTPcMzRFXU/Dyd5BR9P//39DSwMDPUMA)

And wrapped

```
    W B
    i W
I U d ' . ( B ?
@ , ) O . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIFcgQgogICAgaSBXCkkgVSBkICcgLiAoIEIgPwpAICwgKSBPIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=MTkwMQ==&speed=20)

This one does (excluding path changes)

- `IiI` Input integer, input char (-1 for EOI or char value for seperator), Input integer
- `?` Test TOS

  - If 0 `B(`, reverse stack and decrement TOS
  - If positive `B` reverse stack
  - ** negative shouldn't happen **
- `'d,)O@` push 100, integer divide, increment TOS, output and exit

Answer (score 6):

## [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/), 76 bytes

```
HAI 1.2
I HAS A x
GIMMEH x
VISIBLE QUOSHUNT OF SUM OF x AN 99 AN 100
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8nPSc5PSf3/38PRU8FQz4jLU8HDMVjBUaGCy93T19fVA8gI8wz2dPJxVQgM9Q/2CPULUfB3UwgO9QVRFQqOfgqWliDS0MCAyzvEI8Ip0vX/f0NLCxMA)

Comment: _QUOSHUNT._ LOLCODE always cracks me up.

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 11 bytes

```
?({!@/)d':/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99eo1rRQV8zRd1K//9/IwNDAA)

Linear code (9 bytes):

```
?({d':)!@
```

Ungolfed code:

```
  ? ( {
 ! @ / )
d ' : / .
 . . . .
  . . .
```

It may be possible to save 1 or 2 bytes by using `:` to terminate (division by zero error), but I can't find out a way.

Comment: [10 bytes - Almost work, except it doesn't halt](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/18BDOwVNBTUucBMRQVNBSsFfTAnRcFWIVZBT0EPIqUHgRAOhP3/v5GBIQA)

Comment: Just a minor defect..

Answer (score 5):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), <strike>821 807 625 595 570</strike> 386 bytes

```
;
-
)
)
+
+
(                >- >- >- >- >- >- >- >- >- >-)
(                "= "= "= "= "= "= "= "= "= "=+
>       >      >[!![!![!![!![!![!![!![!![!![!!(
"======="======"=##=##=##=##=##=##=##=##=##=##
!(![-)+<!(![(< ![ <  <  <  <  <  <  <  <  <  <<
#=#===="#=#==" #=="=="=="=="=="=="=="=="=="=="=
  >(   ! (<   >))-[!(+
  "====#=="   =====#=:
             !     <
             #====="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLCgMhDLznKxK9JIiHQg99xP0RT3sqhT6g/w826u5hW9bJ4ASJo@Nz/tzfj/l1K@UKEcQqWDH@YIoDyv@8SwMGmFbbRTLRgAwudbhVvB8QiClHCVqVFSmj4j4V7FCzberQt4v2CfbimpjQzK0XiZk4QI1taB6IqfcX2HwMtVW3m76nKuVwPh2/)

<strike>I'm sure this can be golfier</strike> Now this is starting to be quite golfy, though it took me a while to figure out a way to do the division in MarioLANG.

Improvements:

- Lots of bytes saved by taking advantage of the fact that Mario starts falling from the upper left corner of the code.
- Code before a fall has been placed during the fall.
- Great improvement after redesigning the division-by-10 part.

Explanation:

- First we set `a` to `INPUT` as integer and substract `1`.
- Then we set `b` to `0` and `c` equals to 2.
- Then we substract `1` from `a` 10 times, checking every step if `a` has reached `0`.
- If we successfully substract `10` from `a`, increment `b`.
- Repeat this until `a` is `0`. Now we have the result of the division in `b`.
- Substract 1 from `c` and move `b` to `a` if `b` is not `0`. After moving the value `b` is set to `0`.
- Repeat the division-by-10 operation one more time, substracting 1 from `c` again and now that `c` is `0` the program outputs the result in `b` and exits.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```bash
echo $[($1+99)/100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJVpDxVDb0lJT39DAIPb///9ACgA)

*-1 thanks to W W*

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJVpDxVDb0lJT39DAIPb///9ACgA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: 18 bytes, by getting the 1st two bytes of the string and increment -> echo $[${1:0:2}+1]

Comment: @BastianBittorf That fails for numbers < 1000 and multiples of 100.

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 4 bytes

*-5 from @Shaggy*

```
/L c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/X99HIfn/fyMDA0MA)

Comment: You just need to divide by 100 and round up: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=L0wgYw==&input=WwoxOTk5CjIwMDAKMjAwMQpdLW1S

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
M/U
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=TS9V,inputs=MjAwMQ__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```c
f(i){return--i/100+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1Ozuii1pLQoT1c3U9/QwEDb0Lr2f2ZeiUJuYmYeSJarODkxL01DSTVFSUctU9Oaq6AIKA0VAOkHCtX@NzIwMAQA)

-1 byte saved thanks to @luser droog

## 20 bytes

```c
R;f(i){R=--i/100+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/IOk0jU7M6yFZXN1Pf0MBA29C69n9mXolCbmJmHkiGqzg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHLVPTmqugCCgNFQDpBQrV/jcyMDAAAA)

-2 bytes saved thanks to @Digital Trauma

## 18 bytes

```c
f(i){i=--i/100+1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDoIwFET3nOIHY9IiaOtGI8LGUxjjohYKP8FiKpIQwtlrf1y5mpc3MzprtPYrtLr7VDWc30OF/bYtoz/V4SM4bxjyGYssw50UYiPzxaMd4KnQMgLlGp3qVjlIksAjhzkCoGaqlSv2Qh5zEobRspT859XQI5nxJu@cBi8XPobF19CeYF3BpbbDx03EcUqf1DAKHuaL9/IgxBc)

Another -2 bytes saved thanks to @ErikF

Comment: Any tips on improving the score? I feel like a couple bytes could be saved

Comment: If you're OK with a bit of undefined behaviour, you can do [this](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/IOk0jU7M6yFZXN1Pf0MBA29C69n9mXolCbmJmHkiGqzg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHLVPTmqugCCgNFQDpBQrV/jcyMDAEAA) for 20.

Comment: Drop the space after `return`.

Comment: You can reuse the `i` as its own return (18 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYvRCoIwGIXvfYphBJtpbUEUmd70FBFdrOn0B5uxpiDis6/9dNXV@fjOOSprlPIrMKobqppcPq6CftuW0Z/q4Bmc1xTYDEWWwU5wvhH54sE48pJgKIK0jUpVKy1JksAjI3NECDZTLW2x5@KUo9AUl6VgPy9dD2jGu3gwHLxt@Gga30J7JuuKXGvjBjshxyl@Uk0xWJgv3osjP3wB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ErikF that's absolutely amazing

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes <s>([packed](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax))</s>

```
vAJ/^
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=vAJ%2F%5E&i=1946%0A1705%0A1900%0A100%0A2001&a=1&m=2)

Explanation:

```
vAJ/^ Full program, implicit input
v     Decrement
 AJ   Push 100 (102)
   /  Integer division
    ^ Increment
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/)  `-p`, <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```perl
$_=1+--$_/100|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZQW1dXJV7f0MCgxuD/f0MuIIPL0AJCAHmWIJYlkGVkAGQBCcN/@QUlmfl5xf91C3IA)

*(-3 whole bytes, thanks to @Dom Hastings.)*

Or with `-p -MPOSIX`:

#### <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```perl
$_=ceil$_/100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jY5NTNHJV7f0MDg/38jAwODf/kFJZn5ecX/dQv@6/oG@Ad7RgAA)

*(-2 bytes, again thanks to @Dom Hastings.)*

Comment: Solid answer, cant think of a shorter approach right  now! You can drop the parens on `ceil` for -2 and reorder the first using `|0` for a few savings too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZQW1dXJV7f0MCgxuD/f0MuIIPL0AJCAHmWIJYlkGVkAGQBCcN/@QUlmfl5xf91C3IA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings That's what the `|0` in the JS answer was for! (Trying to learn Brachylog left me seeing "alternate predicate" instead of "coerce to int" there.) Thank you. Just in case you're able to make something of it, here's the regex approach that I started with: ``/..?$/;$_=$`+($&>0)`` (I'm now trying to see if I can learn enough Retina to implement this in that).

Comment: Here's a [13 byte](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtvW0tK62FpPT8X6/39DLkMDAy5DCwgB5FmCWJZAlpEBkAUkDP/lF5Rk5ucV/9ctyAEA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") solution that doesn't use any command line module inclusions.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 26 bytes

```
r`(.*)(.?.)
$2*X$1*
X+
_
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/vyhBQ09LU0PPXk@TS8VIK0LFUIsrQpsrnkvv/38jAwMDAA)

My first attempt at Retina. Can probably be golfed more (though, I like the `(.?.)` babyface in this one).

Comment: It seems shorter to use [arithmetic](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4srLp6LK77a0MCgtkbl/38jAwMDAA) unfortunately. Hope you enjoy Retina golfing! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's pretty neat, learnt a few things from that (I stopped reading the Unary arithmetic tutorial page when I realized it was outdated, didn't want to get confused by old syntax). That final `|$` is an especially neat trick for an increment. (And I will, thanks!)

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 6

Assuming input and output on the top-of-stack is OK:

```
99+A0/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2RgYPjf0lLb0UD/f9p/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 12 bytes

```java
y->~-y/100+1
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY/NCoMwEITvPsUeE4o2Kf1BpH2DevFYetj6U2I1iolCKPbV02i9Fi8DO/Oxw5Q4oF9mL5tWqBRcUci3ByCkzrsC0xzi6ZwNKMikhkbOGT0nSqMWKcQg4QzW@JePb7acsQ230ZS3/aNy@YINjcigdgUk0Z2Qz9sdkP6@J0bpvA6aXgeti3QliQwKwsP9kc51/5ETO6whIWNryCqxY4zTZflovw)

**Explanation:**

```java
y->     // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  ~-y   //  Decrease the input by 1
  /100  //  Then integer-divide it by 100
  +1    //  And then add 1
```

Comment: nah, I guess youll have to provide wrapping stuff, too.

Comment: @LMD This has been discussed many times in the meta ever since functions were allowed as alternative for full programs, but Java and C# doesn't need to add the definitions, parameter-types, nor trailing semi-colon to the code for lambdas (recursive methods and imports are a different story of course).

Comment: If I knew those rules... *sniff*

Comment: @LMD Python will still be shorter in 90%+ of the challenges compared to Java lambdas, so don't worry about it too much. ;) This is one challenge where Java is slightly shorter however (compared to the equivalent [18 bytes in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169064/52210)).

Comment: +1, though I prefer `y->--y/100+1` for the sake of readability.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, after posting it and I saw some of the other answers I indeed agree. But since the byte-count and functionality is the same I won't edit it for now. I do agree that it's more readable, and I should have thought about it when posting my answer..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No worries, it's only a personal preference. Your answer is as clear as the suggestion, plus you explain the code, so what more can we ask for? ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <strike>5</strike> 7 bytes

```
~(100/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v07D0MBAX/P/fyMDA0MA)

```
~(100/)
AAA  AA
\\\   \\
 \\\   \Increments the stack
  \\\   Divides the stack
   \\\  
    \\Adds 100 to the stack
     \Decrements the stack
      Turn the input string into an int
```

Comment: Note that e.g. 2001 is in the 21st century. This one works: [`~(100/)`](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmfp1r9v07D0MBAX/N/rWqe1n9DSzNTLkNzAyBhaWDABZThMjIwMAQA "GolfScript – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 13 bytes

```perl6
(*+99)/100+|0
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TY7BTsMwEETv/opRG6GkKYkd0YBrpeLaS7lw5FISF1lKbKtxKhDwZdz4sRDXFXDbebMzu1Ye23IceolTmdWCkO4NV7VpJKoxXqScJzmjNP2go/DWvZO9Q4Vosd1lteme4/ypSfPk@yvbDZ3AHIfW7J3SL7BGaUeIr36cQoLYdq@RhoZGnVBM1w7meOm83iBS2g5uiUi@Wlk72eCdAKqH/ycObvLPXmIWIKrNH50J8jlu9RqM35TkYXBrFJScwS1dBcDuAuCUXgAP4FefZUEp8xoFI9NMfZHPTOs/)

### Expanded:

```perl6
# WhateverCode lambda
(
  *      # this is the parameter
    + 99 # add 99 to adjust the century

) / 100  # divide by 100

+| 0     # Integer bitwise-or with 0 (coerce to Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda x:~-x/100+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqk63Qt/QwEDb8H9afpFCZWpikUJmnkK0oaWlpY6RgYEBiDCMteJSKCjKzCsBK9BR17VT10nTALE1/wMA)

Comment: Putting 100 in seems to return 1.99

Comment: @Acccumulation no?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was Python 2 rather than 3.

Comment: @Acccumulation Duplicate the `/` and it´s both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

```hs
(`div`100).(+99)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WIyElsyzB0MBAU09D29JS839uYmaebUFRZl6JSpqCoYHhfwA)

## 16 bytes

```hs
f x=div(x+99)100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjYls0yjQtvSUtPQwOB/bmJmnm1BUWZeiUqagqGB4X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 22 bytes

```
<?=1+--$argv[1]/100|0;
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WUFtXVyWxKL0s2jBW39DAoMbA@v///4aWFhYA)

```
<?=ceil($argv[1]/100);
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42OTUzR0MlsSi9LNowVt/QwEDT@v///4aWFhYA)

Comment: It's a bit awkward, but you can save 1 byte using `-R`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfkFGgoBukoP4/NTkjX8FQW1dXJbEoPU/f0MCgxsD6v/p/Qy4gk8vQAkIAeZYgliWQZWQAZAEJQwA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Pepe](https://github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 31 bytes

```
rEeEEeeEeeREeEREEEEeeREeEEEReEE
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!c8R_x-3N)

Basically **ceil(n/100)**.

Explanation:

```
rEeEEeeEeeREeEREEEEeeREeEEEReEE - full program

rEeEEeeEee                      - push 100 to stack B
          REeE                  - input as number to stack A. float gets rounded.
              REEEEee           - A / B, or A / 100. push in stack A.
                     REeEEE     - ceil(A)
                           ReEE - output stack A as number
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 19 bytes

```php
<?=ceil($argn/100);
```

or

```php
<?=--$argn/100+1|0;
```

Save to file, run as pipe with `-nF`.

Answer (score 2):

Excel Vba, 89 bytes

```
Function GetCentury(Year As Long)
GetCentury = Mid((Year - 1) / 100, 1, 2) + 1
End Function
```

And a version with 65 bytes

```
Function C(Y As Long)
C = Mid((Y - 1) / 100, 1, 2) + 1
End Function
```

Honestly I dont even know if this is a valid entry :/

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Usually you would state your golfed version first and add a longer version as explanation only. Thus your score 65 bytes. I'm not familiar with VBA, but can you remove some of the spaces in `C = Mid((Y - 1) / 100, 1, 2) + 1`? Finally you may want to check out our [Tips for Golfing in VBA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba). Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), 195 bytes

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:Listen toheart!You is the sum ofa cat the quotient betweenthe sum ofyou a pig the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a big cat!Open heart
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1NC8IwDIb/SnYfpXjczYMHQVDwJMNDVuNW0XZrU9RfX9PJxEPgSfJ@xPGec63WN3zV6oA9CRuGbaOOhhwVaDeOKUCRALoLFNW5bM3ORiYH7AfCwNXJJ7AReCCI6QH@imCQ531Kni05ho74SQI/zVtMCKPtv74pYSA5/4d08lymBOJC1X6U@rk855XW@gM)

#### Explanation:

```
,.Ajax,.Page,.Act I:.Scene I:.[Enter Ajax and Page]Ajax:   #Header

Listen toheart!   # Set Page to the input

# Set Page to (n-1)/(10)**2+1
You is the sum ofa cat the quotient betweenthe sum ofyou a pig the square ofthe sum ofa big big big cat a big cat!

Open heart  # Print Page's value as a number
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <strike>89</strike> 78 bytes

Not perfect but I'm just learning Elixir so code-golf it is!

```
IO.gets("")|>String.to_integer|>(&(Integer.floor_div(100,&1-1)+1)).()|>IO.puts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@v/f018vPbWkWENJSZOrxi64pCgzL12vJD8@M68kNT21CCjmnVqUl5qjp6thCFLhCRHXS8vJzy@KT8ks0zA0MNBEKNOGKvPXKygtKf7/39DAEAA)

In a better format:

```elixir
IO.gets("")                # Get input from terminal
|>String.to_integer        # Make it an int
|>(&(                      # Declare an anonymous function
  Integer.floor_div(100,   # Do a floored division with 100 on the bottom
     &1-1)                  # ... and the integer input minus 1 on top
  +1))                    # Add 1 to the result
  .()                      # Gotta invoke that anonymous for pipes
|>IO.puts                  # Output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>6</s> 7 bytes

```
.EcQ100
```

Explanation:

```
.EcQ100  Implicit print
   Q     Input
  /      Divided by
    100  100
.E       Rounded up
```

Fixed edge case

Comment: I believe this fails the test case for input `1900`.  Should return `19`, instead of `20`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
‹₁ḭ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oC54oKB4bit4oC6IiwiIiwiMjAwMFxuMjAwMVxuMTk0NlxuMTcwNSJd)

#### Explained

```
‹₁ḭ›
‹    # decrement
 ₁ḭ  # divide floor by 100
   › # increment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
(ℍ/)
```

Pretty straightforward...

Thanks to Mr. Xcoder and [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16522/81420) for getting me interested in this cool but relatively unused language!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X@NRS6@@5v//huYGpgA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan True, edited.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
q100/kQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v9DQwEA/O/D/fyMDA0MA)

Comment: Wouldn’t `100/Xk` do?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
÷ȷ2Ċ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9hPbjY50/f//38jAwAAA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 10 bytes

```
?(_100/)!@
```

Same method as my Gaia answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXiPe0MBAX1PR4f9/Q0sDAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 19 bytes

```
{y:Int->(y+99)/100}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTBbtswDL37K9iih6RLYztY2zloC3RFNwQr0MNy2VGx6ViILHmSnNYI@u0ZKSdZ2suwky2RenrvkdTKeCX1Nj6HB4vCYwGlseAr6SA3BcLSqBLySiiFeonTqPK@cdM45iDHxs6LfIWvlELxcW7q@HeLzkujXZxeZcnVJPqOnhARctS@tR2YEgR0KGwU/TKthcaapRU1VMKBN/RZIwgdMkDJFUKaXV5zZIEBR@qm9ZRR8EqDaT2vP9zgK@EDxDiKvpEkfBV1o0hBNNNTQvx8FT23fgqTpN@4Ti77jfTLLiNJdhtZv3FYh@UkSVJewySNogXmonUYYIGskzrQmSS@2nMiGj8QGw7VMlAnfgSSgKtMqwoWd5wPxJk5HIXpaJq9Q5xXaJEKhqNwXymt8wcA1wjtoLSmDsFgZwptw06yeVLnqi2kXh6Fk6RHcpgbSrn4eDz5B8CEAdDnxO1ed/vK1pyjqEFasUT2h9rJvFCvMcqKXem4D0LDkVzbF9e9IPoxTIeEVRSSW0ooeDj0IsxJJFNRzuy4kAXKkK9roagJo/M4iuIYHl/JiYKuW6N1hAKiCKyzjI8H3o2V3PaG0wu5liG@6NgQ6CSqg8qD92WrWV6Ozg0YYgoz7YdwGwGE9acsG8bcMww5p4mAwkoisJsv/DtUPVYtpB4Iu3RTuLdWdDc/vaVL74awiQiTQJ5EvSgEUHLOXgSgIxBg1dAEBpSdZsTfo9tuuikxu7gbdHtKb9uQwfbRzL8vIBu/kwXSM6qntA19e/yQdBvOPUmNg@HJydgbumAwDDmy7OXDDaT9DiFU1rzAjIguhbq3y7YmEx9fc2xYx@B0pglZFgH75LQ/RQXRXlHwLKD1M3W2aQL48O1QB0rv9T5rGvEd5IhaiYadHH2nh0UWWIpWecfKCEX4vIIBWmuogHPmKRYKhzvBBxJfRdG/OiNoHfu1h9nTZWvIbO/IGyWdfy4H/BaMwrsyCoM86qeL343@DNev94qfCz68N@w/xLMKUk9FisIPt9H2Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash + coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 18 bytes

```bash
bc<<<"($1+99)/100"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PynZxsZGSUPFUNvSUlPf0MBA6f///0DKAAA)

Comment: When shell submissions use external programs we typically mention that in the language field to distinguish them from pure shell solutions. So in this case consider specifying the language as "Bash + coreutils" or "Bash + `bc`".

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
[S S S T    N
_Push_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][S N
S _Duplicate_1][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  S S T   _Subtract][S S S T  T   S S T   S S N
_Push_100][T    S T S _Integer_divide][T    S S S _Add][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

-1 byte thanks to *@aschepler*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZNLgUsBgji5OEFAAUgBxUFyEJqLU4ETwgeq@f/f0NLAAAA).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer n = STDIN as integer
n = n - 1
n = n integer-divided by 100
n = n + 1
Print n as integer to STDOUT
```

Comment: You can take off one byte by removing one Dup (-3) and replacing the Swap (-3) with a Push 1 (+5).

Comment: @aschepler Ah, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```scala
def f(a:Int)=(a-1)/100+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQ/T8lNU0hTSPRyjOvRNNWI1HXUFPf0MBA2/B/QVFmXklOnkaahqGliZmmJheSgLmBKaqApYEBqgAa38jAwBAowFX7HwA)

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 33 bytes, with floats

```scala
def f(a:Float)=(Int)((a-1)/100)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFBQ/T8lNU0hTSPRyi0nP7FE01bDM69EU0MjUddQU9/QwEBT2/B/QVFmXklOnkaahqGliZmmJheSgLmBKaqAJVAPigAa38jAwBAowFX7HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [TeaScript](https://teascript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), 8 bytes

```javascript
Mc(x / h
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22Mc(x%20%2F%20h%22&inputs=%5B%221990%22%5D&opts=%7B%22ev%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22nox%22:true%7D)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
(100/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flFn9X8PQwEBf839t3X9DSwMDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 7 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-_-.01*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/XzdeV8/AUMvQ0sRMwdDcwFTB0NLAQMEQiI0MDAz//wcA)

**Explanation:**

Pretty trivial... almost looks like an emoji `(-_-)`:

```
-_-.01* / the solution
      * / multiply input by
   .01  / 0.01
  -     / negate  \
 _      / floor    - ceiling the result 
-       / negate  /
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 6 bytes

When given only one argument, `sub(` divides it by 100.

```
sub(Ans+99
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/MATLAB, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```matlab
@(x)(x+49)/100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0JTo0LbxFJT39DA4H@aRmZeibGRhqGliZmmpoKCqoKtgpEBF1zY3MAUJmxogRC2NDCAC1sihA0MFODCcFEjAwNDuNGG/wE)

Managed to save a byte by requiring the input to be provided as an integer not a double.

This anonymous function takes an integer as an input, and returns the required value.

MATLAB/Octave when dividing integers performs rounding rather than truncation (Why Mathworks? Why?!). To convert rounding to ceil, we need to add on 49 to the number prior to division.

---

Original, perhaps uninteresting answer:

```matlab
@(x)ceil(x/100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzOTUzR6NC39DAQPN/moahpYmZpoKCqoKtgpEBF5BvbmAK5RtagPiWQHVQviWIb2CgAOMDuUYGBoYw7Yb/AQ)

Anonymous function to find the result. Just the standard `ceil()` of dividing by 100.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 13 bytes

An anonymous function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the console.

```vb
?[A1-1]\100+1
```

Comment: Hahaha. I went all way in creating a function

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 18 bytes

```
lambda x:-(x/-100)
```

Taking advantage of the fact `/` divides towards 0, we make a impromptu ceil division, assuming all inputs are positive which is the case according to the spec. Would work in Python 3 with `//` but it's golfier in Py2.

Uses `ceil(year/100)`

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, <s>29</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
(ceiling(/ x 100))
```

Or, if variable definitions aren't allowed, **21 bytes**

```
(ceiling(/(read)100))
```

Pretty self-explanatory, can be tested with something along these lines:

```
(setf x 1900)
(print (ceiling (/ x 100)))
```

Comment: a snippet is not allowed (i.e. you can't assume `x` is defined)

Comment: @ASCII-only I assumed it was allowed, considering most of the other answers rely on a variable/state being already defined.  For example, both Excel answers, TI-Basic, Octave/Matlab

Comment: Well, Excel is kinda a special case (it's not even a programming language), Ans in TI-BASIC can be considered STDIN (well, at least I think so), and Octave/Matlab defines a lambda

Comment: I’d argue that Ans in TI basic is definitely a variable. It performs like one in all TI Basic programs. However, when I get home, I’ll amend my answer to better accommodate those rules.

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it, you're right. Then in that case I'd say that answer is invalid as well

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
def f(n);(n-1)/100+1;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc5BCoMwEIXhvafILgkivhcQG8TLiGYZSlsXPX00xtpxM/wDH8O81umb0rwEFUy0g4kNbUug5rDEOT3Xz1vRO1RHBZPblkWPykGXLpM9ugvu/Yd83KGHuAhxkb7A0wl2UxI5gD@VW7xHnTY)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 19 bytes

```c
f(x){x=x/100.+.99;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0KzusK2Qt/QwEBPW8/S0rr2f25iZp6GpkI1lwIQFBRl5pWkaSippsTkKekopGkYWpqYaWpa45A0NzDFLWlpYIBbEo@ckYGBIUiy9j@QZQAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Vim (5 bytes)

```
99^AXx
```

This code looks for number at or on the right of the cursor, adds 99 (`^A99`) and divides it by 100 (`Xx`).

Note: `^A` is single byte (0x1 – Start Of Heading).

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 11 bytes

```
@1A554WWPM:
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%401A554WWPM%3A&input=1923)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Razetime

Comment: [9 bytes](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%40554WWPM%3A&input=2001)

Comment: @Razetime your variant doesn't handle edge cases like 1900. However, still saved some bytes by adding `1A`

Comment: oh, silly mistake in that one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```go
func(y int)int{return^-y/100+1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NasMwEIX3OsWQlU0nrmT6Ext0h-5LW4SRgkgtybJcMEIn6caU9hw9R25TKeniMd_AvHnv8-totzM4MZzEUcIotCF6dNaHZqfGsCMfwoPiP0tQ-8OvWsxQraBNqLOil2Hx5nW_3jJKb1i6Xp2_w-okOJiDX4YQNdriSKS4LwlVDZG4uefPLy5G1t09YEsTRvZI75EdCnWUIusKFcizpRkuV5kYtizlh9bDG0roOXhhcn03RzL1XFWy0TV58jn23ZQFJ5SNLeJ8qkki_1237Tr_AA)

- -2 by @Steffan: `(y-1) => ^-y`

Comment: `(y-1)` => `^-y`

Answer (score 0):

## [befunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) 11 bytes

`&1-aa*/1+.@@`

- `&` read input,
- `1-` subtract one (2000 is 20th century)
- `aa*/` divide by 100
- `1+` add one
- `.` print
- `@` end

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, <s>15</s> <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 13 bytes

```
=INT(99%+A1%)
```

Input is in cell `A1`

Comment: Does `=LEFT(A1+99,2)` work?  I don't know Excel.

Comment: @WW It would except it has the same failure I just noted in my original: Fails on years <= 1000. I used that method on the new formula, though, to save a byte.

Comment: Doesn't `=CEILING(A1/100,1)` work for 18 bytes?

Comment: @Neil Maybe, yes. Maybe I clearly didn't spend enough time on this because I saw it as a relatively easily challenge and overlooked some pitfalls and optimizations.

Comment: If you want to go the extra mile, in `pt-br` version is `=TETO(A1/100;1)`

Comment: @EngineerToast Change `A1/100` to `A1%` for 15 bytes, or adapt the `LEFT` version to `=INT(99%+A1%)` for 13 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## APL (Dyalog), 6 bytes

```
⌈⎕÷100
```

My first APL answer!

Thanks to @dzaima for saving me a load of bytes!

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@oo12h@P@jno5HfVMPbzc0MACJ/C/mMrQ0MAAA)

Comment: @dzaima That's a stupid rule...

Comment: Well blame the people who didn't believe in year 0 :p

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈∕Ｎ¹⁰⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sRhIpGbmZOala7hklmWmpGp45hWUlviV5ialFmlo6igYGhhoAoH1//9GBoYW/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ¹⁰⁰ Literal 100
   Ｎ    Input number
  ∕     Floating-point division
 ⌈      Ceiling
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 7 bytes

```
I100/UP
```

[**Try it online**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=STEwMC9VUA&input=MTk0OA)

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 19 bytes

```
y->Math.ceil(y/100)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hc27DoIwFAbgnac4YzuAxXiJIfoGsDAah9oWLZZCaCFpDM9ei7IalpNz@U7@mo40rvnLM0WNgZxK/Y4ApLairygTUMwjAG@HuxJQoaVxOAv7KQrFWGolgwI0nMG7@JJT@0yYkAq5TUoI9tnMuvAX2KLHVnJoQhoqbS/143oDin9RpTNWNEk72KQLJ6s00kmF0tPuwPE39r85kv2qORGyatbJlpB0MVM0@Q8)

In java, the `ceil` function helps. Input and output are both `double`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! This question is code golf, so you want to make your submission as short as possible (I believe you can remove the spaces.) Also please provide a header with the name of the language you submitted and your answer's bytecount.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your code currently seems to give [a few incorrect answers](https://tio.run/##hZBNDoIwEIX3nGKW7YJajD8hRG8gG5bGRS1Fi1AILSSN4ew4KFvDZpKZ9817kynFIMIyf02yEtbCRWjzDgC0caorhFSQzi1A3vT3SkFBUAFPExyOARbrhNMSUjBwgslDeEYP92RS6Yr4TcQ5TaZkJls0QHJZGBqdQ41pJHOdNo/rDQT9RWXeOlWzpnesRclVhhhWkCjeHeg3@D9y5Ps1JMaLVpBVYst5RJcfjNMH).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it does happen to work if you take input as a double instead of an int...

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh, didn't notice that but you're right. I've edited the answer to our standards. Please take a look at it so you can see how to do it yourself next time _akhil7886_. And once again welcome to PPCG.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen BTW you don't need the `d`s after the year: https://tio.run/##hZC9DoIwEIB3n@LGdqAW408I0TeAhdE41FK0WAqhhaQxPHstympYLvfzXb7L1WxkUV2@PFfMGMiY1O8NgNRW9BXjAvK5BCjb4a4EVGhJHE5Df9qEYCyzkkMOGs7gXXTJmH0SLqRCbhtTin06Y13YC9hCj60soQk2VNhe6sf1Bgz/VIUzVjSkHSzpwsgqjTSpUJzsj/hr/Y@c6GENScJBK8gqsaM0xssDJv8B

Comment: @BetaDecay Ah, you're completely right. Ah well, now it's perhaps more clear the inputs are doubles (just thinking of a good excuse here, lol). ;p

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
print((int(input())-1)//100+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQwNEZOYVlJZoaGrqGmrq6xsaGGgbav7/b2hpYAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 12 bytes

```
_(.99+?/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 21 bytes

```lua
print((...-1)//100+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PT9dQU1/f0MBA21Dz////RgYGhgA)

I'm not sure if I can get the year as an argument, but that's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

**EXCEL, 17 bytes**

`A1` as input

`=ROUNDUP(A1/100,)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 68 bytes

```
({}[()])<>((((((()()()){}){}){}()){}){})({<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>()})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6NlpDM1bTxk4DAjRBULO6FoLgTI1qGw2gWiAXoaO2utZOQ7NW8/9/IwMDAwA)

Pushing the number `100` is longer than the div algorithm itself! Calculates `(n-1)/100+1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 147 bytes

```
,>,>,>,>>++++++++[-<++++++>]<[->+<<-<-<-<->>>>]<[-<+>]<[<+>[-]]<[->+>+<<]>>>++++++++++[-<->]+<[<[-<+>]>>-<[-]]>[<<<<+>>>>-]>[-<<<<<+>+>>>>]<<<<<.>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoBQCEQPZH4IahHIXERcVBBE0CLo/KYZNAPi6GOWa97P7V4P9w5l0CdlqQUmyiARLiOUJ3k/MZWtkIQMf8VbwjAKrHiAJXGohCirOAJLRaruVENz74dxegA)

## Explanation

```
,>,>,>,>                 input
>++++++++[-<++++++>]     store a '0'
<[- >+<                  save '0'
 <-<-<-<->>>>            subtract '0'
]
<[-<+>]                  move 10^0 to 10^1
<[                       check if 10^1 has a non-zero value
 <+>                     increment 10^2
 [-]                     exit
]
<[->+>+<<]               copy 10^2 twice
>>>
++++++++++               store a ten
[-<->]                   subtract ten
+                        flag for if check
<                        if zero then carry
[                        not zero
 <[-<+>]                 put 10^2 one to the left
 >>-<[-]
]>
[                        it was zero so carry
 <<<<+>>>>-
]
>[-<<<<<+>+>>>>]<<<<<.>. print
```

Comment: This does not work for years below 1000. I also tried to think of a solution in brainfuck but I couldn't get past this limitation.

Comment: @Charlie Well, if you fill your input with leading zeros it does.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 14 bytes

```
n=>n/100+.99|0
```

Since the century is roughly `year/100 + 1`, minus an offset of 1 year, it can be calculated like `(n+99)/100`. This is then rounded down to an integer in the last two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 14 bytes

```ruby
->n{~-n/100+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuk43T9/QwEDbsPZ/tKGliZmOgqG5gSmQtDQwAJIgwsjAwDBWLzUxOUOhuqasRqGgtKRYQUm5uqxWwdZOQbk6Lbostlap9j8A)

I think it's squeezed as much as possible. I would love to see if anyone has any clever tricks to make this smaller.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 16 bytes

```
->i{(i-1)/100+1}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 18 bytes

```swift
print((n-1)/100+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQp2Cr4JlXolGUmpjik5mXqqGpqKn4v6AoEyimkadrqKlvaGCgbaj5/7@RgYEBAA)

`n` is the input of the program

Answer (score 0):

## x86_64 machine language on Linux, 12 bytes

```
0:   97                      xchg   %eax,%edi
1:   ff c8                   dec    %eax
3:   6a 64                   pushq  $0x64
5:   59                      pop    %rcx
6:   99                      cltd   
7:   f7 f9                   idiv   %ecx
9:   ff c0                   inc    %eax
b:   c3                      retq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/19DK01TQ9NWKabC0jymws0tpsLZIqbCzBGITWIqTC2B4kDsBpKzhMobALGxkvX/zLwShdzEzDwNzWouhYIiIDdNQ0k1JSZPSSdNw8jAwEBT0xpTwtDcwBS7hKWJGQ4JXEbhEAfabQiSqP0PYgEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 51 bytes

A nice easy one to finish the week after [this monstrosity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210949/58974)!

```
listen to Y
let Y be-1
let Y be/100
turn up Y
say Y
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 18 bytes

```ruby
:pred|~:/&100|:+&1
```

`:+&-1` is equivalent to `:pred` but IMO `:pred` is prettier. Alas `:+&1` is shorter than `:succ`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWm6wKilJTauqs9NUMDQxqrLTVDCESN82iDS1NzHQUDM0NTIGkpYEBkAQRRgYGhrF6qYnJGQop-VwKCgWlJcUKbtHxhrFcqXkpEN0LFkBoAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ɦ/ṃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy04u03-4s3lJcVJyMVRowRJDSxMzCBsA)

##### Explanation

```python
ɦ/ṃ  #      input
ɦ    #              100
 /   #            /
  ṃ  # ceil(           )
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
'c+SppJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/189WTu4oMDr/39DSwNDAA)

This uses the `(N+99)` trick other code uses to get the right century for `xx00` years.  After that it converts the result to a string and prints the first two digits.

```
'c       - push 99 onto the stack
  +      - add number on STDIN to 99
   S     - split number to digits
    pp   - delete two least significant digits
      J  - recombine the remaining two digits into a number
```

The stack prints as number by default when the program exits