# Double Prime Words

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, primes

Consider a word/string of length \$n\$, only including the letters A-Z, a-z. A word/string is a double prime word if and only if n is prime and the sum of the letters, s, is also prime, using their numeric position in the alphabet (`a=1, B=2, c=3`, etc.).

Input can be any combination of upper or lower case alphabetic characters,  as there is no numeric difference between `a` or `A`.

Output is any appropriate logical format related to your language. i.e. True or False, T or F, 1 or 0, etc. Specifying what format your output will appear is highly appreciated, but not required. (Output need not include n, s, but I include them below as demonstration and example)

Winning condition is shortest code in bytes able to detect if a string is a double prime, fitting both conditions for n and s to be prime. (I've now included cases from all 4 possible situations of n, s.)

### Examples

```
Input -> Output (n, s)

Prime -> True (5, 61)
han -> True (3, 23)
ASK -> True (3, 31)
pOpCoRn -> True (7, 97)
DiningTable -> True (11, 97)
METER -> True (5, 61)

Hello -> False (5, 52)
SMILE -> False (5, 58)
frown -> False (5, 76)

HelpMe -> False (6, 59)
John -> False (4, 47)
TwEnTy -> False (6, 107)

HelloWorld -> False (10, 124)
Donald -> False (6, 50)
telePHONES -> False (10, 119)

A -> False (1, 1) 
C -> False (1, 3) {1 is not prime}
d -> False (1, 4)
```

Comment: The main point of the Sandbox is to get feedback, and because of this we usually leave a challenge in for around 3 days. 1 hour is far too short, and because of that, this challenge is still, unfortunately, still unclear IMO. For example, you say "Consider a word/string of length n, only including the letters A-Z, a-z" but then go on to say "If input is a phrase or sentence, strip any numbers, punctuation, special characters, and spaces". This is an interesting challenge, but I think you didn't leave it in the Sandbox long enough

Comment: Things to avoid when writing challenges: [The prime numbers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14580/20260)

Comment: Testing the primality of **n** is enough to give the correct answer for all test cases. You may want to add one for which it doesn't hold.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Sorry to jump to posting this challenge so quickly, I merely felt that "only including the letters A-Z, a-z" was synonymous with stripping "numbers, punctuation, special characters, and spaces." I'll clarify this time, and wait longer for any further challenges.

Comment: The opening sentence states that the input will only contain letters but, later on, the opposite is stated. Which is it?

Comment: @xnor I understand the struggle with primes. I felt that this challenge was simpler because it's merely checking if an easy-to-sum number is prime, rather than computing a prime.

Comment: @Sumner18 Don't worry too much about it. As long as you're paying attention to a challenge, it's usually possible to rescue even the worst challenges (and this is a long way from that). I'd just recommend editing in any clarifications you make in the comments into the questions, and being available to answer people's questions. From that, other users will help find and close the edge cases/confusing language that you may have overlooked.

Comment: @All Edits have been made to clarify input, and more edge cases have been provided.

Comment: Suggested test case: `C`. This should be falsey, as the length (1) is not prime, even though the sum (3) is prime.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ŒuO_64µL,SẒP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opFL/eDOTQ1t9dIIf7poU8P9w@6OmNZH//0crBRRl5qYq6SgoZSTmgSjHYG8Q5QHUmB@eX5STAuUV@IJV@bqGuAYpxQIA)

### How it works

```
ŒuO_64µL,SẒP - Main link, takes string s as argument e.g. s = "Prime"
Œu           - Convert to upper case                          "PRIME"
  O          - Convert to ordinals                            [80, 82, 73, 77, 69]
   _64       - Subtract 65 (call this L)                      [16, 18, 9, 13, 5]
      µ      - Start a new link with L as the left argument
       L     - Take the length                                5
         S   - Take the sum                                   61
        ,    - Pair the two values                            [5, 61]
          Ẓ  - Take primality of each                         [1, 1]
           P - Take product                                   1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 59 bytes

```ruby
->a{[a.size,a.upcase.bytes.map{|i|i-64}.sum].all? &:prime?}
```

+33 bytes after correcting the solution, thanks to DrQuarius.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBdb4IwFIbv@ysaL@aaIAFFmEvULBuL@2AaJdmF8aLMgzQpbVckxqm/ncHMMnC3z/Oec95W59G@GEawYQLNNEsBd0Y41Dng676BXZughIo/1jNwt0fQ3eKlwXplTk3VvZzXsp6BBx5BD0wwsQlpxGu7bfssAz/05/9OoglwLiv8SHl25v0uQYvg6dW/wDcExVruRBN77nmLCqAm3DI/IOhZJvW4Y2CnrBLufBHum2nb8n7bvEvN1zVrW6XuOuX7pKANU12xCNoCh9lk@uYvLqfsssMQxBohDZ8504Dbqvr6NoqHRWdED0tqZuwLDGrm6oNmYEb7LWRmStXhyI6s4zonM8vTlUk5H@Or25/p8alQOF62mMhAb3ECGlqr4hs) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZVFdb4IwFH3vr2h4mCNBIoowTdQsG4v7YBol2YPzocyqTWrp@Ihh6m9nBewE93bPuef23p4TJn6aDXy8IQxMQ7LDsDmEXphgeNvVoGWoYIvYhetosN1Rwf38tcZ1hI5P@EMwq2htDfZsFTwSRtjGQz6tvG0YZdN1PGf2byUYY0qDnH5CNCr5blsFc/f5zbmi71SwDoM9q9O2Vb7CXVxpWELfU8FLsK3KTQ2a4hRv7zAvrauNli2v@QhCuqp0jZZot03xv4ChWiff0lJBjCmejifvzvx6yhA3DDBbARDi74SEGDZ4bn0DrAdZc4gOC6RH5AdrSE/4F4qw7qcxjvQd4ocjOZKmZZ70KNktdUTpCN70i@nRKeNJHEFFWBlvUygm4qivAA7XC6WIVlmWQCQqSxGkLM/5SViJTVJFWAKAcs8nyz91tajwSg4UeUlQpCRBGY1EeSCyLmOo6M7W/91V2C3RxWRlmf0C)

Comment: This code does not solve this puzzle at all.
[Your TiO link intentionally left out the two truthy cases it fails](https://tio.run/##ZVFba8IwFH4/vyLkQQ1WsVbtHOgYW4e7OMUW9uBkVIxaqEmXtogb@@1dmi7Yuqec75Kck/OJdH3KRmu6CxjMRXCgqDVGnkgpavQNNDAJ7H125iwDdS0Ct@5zhbOkL5pFd3xR8toGGtoE7gMWsJ3nr8PS26ZZiFPHcxb/WsKEhiHP6Qc/jAu@3yXgTh9fnAv6isBW8COr0vageCWa0pIwkP4hgSe@L9t7BurJUbyjw7xT1W12bD3NGxfhpqSaHSl3e/J/nPkVJe/SIZDQkM4ns1fHvbxlyhlGlG0ABP1MA0FRPcpXX4ftKGuN/e9lw2/HwRet1eSZHkhbyTcGbuBmobQT/hEbSlVlExO8@smiNIkRlrtM9ieU0DiJrzFEaLvEKlu8KoCMVJcySV3@BahhKTdNqbQkgKLPO8t/ddFILUtfUIFpoGLS4LxTvMp@AQ): DiningTable, METER

Comment: It was not intentional. I will correct the solution.

Comment: Sorry to imply it was, the two examples it failed being removed seemed suss. I posted a solution in Ruby that solves it in 50 bytes ([TiO](https://tio.run/##ZVFbT8IwFH4/v6LZg1AzFgZjExIwRmdARQgs8QF5GFJgyehqu4VM42@f3WbDhm/9Lqfn8vFkk2bDDdkHFOY8OBLUGiGPJwQ1ezqyTQwHn565ro46XQx3y@ca15U@NmP30aLidXTUdzA8BDSge8/fhJW/TbMUp67nLv61hDEJwyinH/1QlHyvg2E5nby4F/QNhh2PTrROO3b5C5uSimBLfx/DU3So2i0dWXIU7@RSL627zbajpnmLeLitqGZbyh1L7hdRv6bkXdoYYhKS@Xj26i4vq0w5w5DQLQAnn0nACWqw/PQN2A2z1kh8r4Qhgi@iCyNhH74ghkiOLdu6Lum1cfRZ82pQ1Nzin4wlsUCavGB8SFFMRCwGGjC0W2lFotq6BDJI9ZT5qedfbApW0lJUkZEEUPZ5p/kuF42KE6mCIiYFinAUOF9SW2e/))

Comment: I don't know if arrays are considered truthy, but nice solution. I just fixed mine.

Comment: Thanks, and yes you're right, arrays are truthy in MATL iff all elements are true, so I thought I could cut that corner. Added ".all?" so my solution is now 55 bytes. Thanks. PS Is it allowed to hide "require 'prime'" in the header? I followed your lead on that, but didn't know it was allowed.

Comment: prime is part of the ruby standard library, so from what I remember, it doesn't count.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112952/discussion-between-razetime-and-drquarius).

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>68</s> 71 bytes

+3 bytes to correct a bug pointed out by Dominic van Essen

```r
`?`=sum;s=?b<-utf8ToInt(scan(,""))%%32;l=?b^0;l-1&5>?c(!s%%1:s,!l%%1:l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8E@wba4NNe62NY@yUa3tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR0lJU1NV1djIOgcoHWdgnaNrqGZqZ5@soVisqmpoVayjmAOiczT/BxRl5qb@BwA)

Notice that to convert both upper and lower case letters to the integers 1...26, we can take the ASCII codepoint modulo 32. `sum(!x%%1:x)` is a golfy way of counting the number of divisors of `x`, which will be equal to 2 iff `x` is prime.

Ungolfed:

```r
`?` = sum                       # shorthand for sum
b = utf8ToInt(scan(, "")) %% 32 # take input and convert to ASCII, then take mod 32
s = sum(b)
l = sum(b^0)                    # l = length(b)
5 > sum(c(!s%%1:s,!l%%1:l))    # sum the number of divisors of s and l, and check whether you get <5.
       & l!=1                   # and that l is not 1
```

Comment: The ingenuity is palpable! The shorthand, the modulus, the method for getting length! It's beautiful! True Art from the Language of the Month and my language of choice! Have an upvote!

Comment: @Robin - I think that checking the sum of the sums of divisors fails for ["D"](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8E@wba4NNe62NY@yUa3tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR0lJU1NV1djIOgcoHWdgbWJra5@soVisqmpoVayjmAOiczT/u/wHAA).  I fell into the same trap, and only realized while I was writing it up...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! Fixed, at the cost of 3 bytes.

Comment: Ah!  If you fix it like that, I think you can lose a byte with ```5>``` instead of ```4==```, right?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yup, it's already there! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## perl -Mfeature=say -MList::Util=sum -pl, 95 bytes

```
s/[^a-z]//gi;$m=sum map-64+ord,split//,uc;$_=(1 x y===c)!~/^(11+)\1+$|^1$/&&(1x$m)!~/^(11+)\1$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NC4IwAEDv@xULhigqY1AdlB06CEEJ0QcdKkN01GBzY5tgEf30Ft46dHu8d3maGTHz3uJTVafPC8Y3niNJbS@hrHU6n8bKtInVgjuMk77J0ZWGBA7wQSltoskbVyEhcXQmMXpVBOEgCMmA5G9B2PuN4ZKBe92BxW4FlkwIBY/KiHZkDUsGymJfbD9KO64669Nyza3LsoPjYrz5I7T4Ag)

### How does it work?

```
s/[^a-z]//gi;   # Clean the input, remove anything which isn't an ASCII letter.

                          uc;     # Upper case the string
                  split//,        # Split it into individual characters
          -64+ord                 # Calculate its value: 
                                  #           subtract 64 from its ASCII value
       map                        # Do this for each character, return a list
$m=sum                            # Sum the values, and store it in $m

     y===c                        # Returns the length of the input string
(1 x y===c)                       # Length of the input string in unary

/^(11+)\1+$|^1$/                  # Match a string consisting of a composite
                                  # number of 1's, or a single 1
!~                                # Negates the match, so
(1 x y===c)1~/^(11+)\1+$|^1$/     # this is true of the input string (after
                                  # cleaning) has prime length

(1x$m)!~/^(11+)\1+$/              # Similar for the sum of the values --
                                  # note that the value is at least 2, so
                                  # no check for 1.
```

Combining this, and the program will print 1 on lines which match
the conditions, and an empty line for lines which do not match.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDsEKhWD86UbcqVl8lV9fWzEQ3vyhFoTRZRU0/PVNPRUnPsEIlV1OxTj8mSUPD0FBbM8ZIu8ZQMyZJ/7@1Sq6tgbVKMpD478wVUJSZm8qVkZjH5RjszeWRmpOTrxCeX5STAmIX@KZy@bqGuAb9yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F@3IAcA "Perl 5 – Try It Online"), essentially using your logic.  Eliminates the command line module inclusion.

Comment: Oops, make that [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDsEKhWD86UbcqVl8lV9fWzEQ3vyhFoTRZRU0/PTNVT0VJz7BCJVdTsU4/JklDw9BQWzPGSLvGUDMmSf@/tUqurbq69X9HRy5nroCizNxUrozEPC7HYG8uj9ScnHyF8PyinBQQu8A3lcvXNcQ16F9@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugU5AA "Perl 5 – Try It Online").  I forgot a `/e` on the substitution.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gAIlk>O‚pP
```

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3dEzJ9vO/1HDrIKA//@jlQKUdJSKgDgTiHOBOFUpFgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXwoZX/0x0PrcvJtvN/1DCrIOC/zv9opYCizNxUJR2ljMQ8IOkY7A0kC/wLnPODQHyXzLzMvPSQxKQckBpf1xDXICDtkZqTkw@kg309fVyBdFpRfnkeRLzAF6TQKz8DxA8pd80LqYRpCM8vykkBmZmflwhmlKTmpAZ4@Pu5BivFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
g           # Get the length of the (implicit) input-list
 A          # Push the lowercase alphabet
  I         # Push the input-list of characters
   l        # Convert the input to lowercase
    k       # Get the (0-based) index of each character in the alphabet-string
     >      # Increase each by 1 to make them 1-based indices
      O     # Take the sum of that
       ‚    # Pair the length together with this sum
        p   # Check for both whether they're a prime (1 if it's a prime; 0 if not)
         P  # And check if both are truthy by taking the product of the pair
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [`gIÇ5o%O‚pP`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3fNwu2m@qv@jhlkFAf//BxRl5qYCAA) works with strings as input at the same length.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
function(s,S=sum,t=S(utf8ToInt(s)%%32))S(!nchar(s)%%1:t)^S(!t%%1:t)==4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNawIxFEX3/RVWERJwo3VRCllITVHrqJhAd5VUM51AfG/IB@Kvn1q7qFR5XSXcc3IvJDQubnaYP7zd1MHtrWjKDNvkEFjsKRHzvpeEYjmVjxqnkFjk3e7DgHPF7mFbmXAO@k@Jv5@S9HMVYvi3l7VX30ebtzqtFLK9u@KVAYKO1CtB62X9jGvq/diBg09tThFhFVLL9S@/FibWezwLpfHxRoMqpnNJCS8BD3Ah3NyoC0t1zLACiuuDBH38b8TjGwa/o4rGCIY2kvV2NVkupCLnRuQK@V8XsPkC)

I forced myself not to peek at [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210733/double-prime-words/210808#210808) before having a shot at this, and (satisfyingly) it turns out that we've used some rather different golfing tricks.

`t` is the total of all letter indices.  This is certain to be greater-than-or-equal-to `nchar(s)` (it's only equal if the string `s` is "A" or "a").  So we can use modulo `1:t` to test for primality of the string length instead of modulo `1:nchar(s)`, and there's no need waste characters on a variable declaration to store `nchar(s)`.

Both primality tests `sum(!t%%1:t)` and `sum(!nchar(s)%%1:t)` must be equal to 2 if both the sum-of-letter-indices and the string length are prime.
We could check if they're both 2, but this requires `==2` twice (plus a `&` or equivalent), which seems wasteful.  Is it ok to check that the total is 4?  The edge-case we need to worry about is if one of them equals 1 and the other 3: this happens for the string "D" (length=1 and character-index=4 with divisors 1,2 and 4).  So it's not Ok.  Can we multiply them?  Also no, because 1 and 4 will again give 4 (think about the string "F").
But - since we know that the string length must be less-than-or-equal to the sum-of-character-indices, we can use exponentiation: the only way to get 4 is 4^1 or 2^2, and since the sum-of-character-indices can't be 1 if the string-length is 4, 2^2 is the only possibility.

So the final, combined check for double-primality is `sum(!nchar(s)%%1:t)^sum(!t%%1:t)==4`, saving 3 characters compared to testing them separately.

Comment: Wow! I don't even know what to express here! It seems so detailed, but so methodical! Well done!

Answer (score 4):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>327</s> <s>321</s> <s>319</s> 294 bytes

No built-in for testing primes!
No case conversion!
No way to get the codepoint of a character!

Why do I do these things to myself?! Spent so long just getting the damn thing to work, I'm sure it's far from optimally golfed but it'll do for now.

Outputs `0.25` for `true` and `0` for false.

```
F takes N
let D be N
let P be N-1
while P and D-2
let D be-1
let M be N/D
turn M up
let P be N/D-M

give P

G takes I
N's 27
while N
cast N+I in C
if C's S at X
give N

let N be-1

give G taking 64

listen to S
X's 0
T's 0
while S at X
let T be+G taking 96
let X be+1

say F taking T*F taking X
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

```
PrimeQ@*Tr/@(LetterNumber@#&&1^#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoMzc10EErpEjfQcMntaQktcivNDcptchBWU3NME5ZUw2kJK9EQd8h3UHLOSOxKDEZqKZY36FaCaxXSUcpIzEPSDoGewNJj9ScnHyF8PyinBQIr8AXpMTXNcQ1SKn2/38A)

-22 bytes from **@att**

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoMzc10EErpEjfQcMntaQktcivNDcptchBWU0tLDGnNLXYASLsnF@aV1LsoKypBtKUV6Kg75Cu71CtBDZBSUcpIzEPSDoGewNJj9ScnHyF8PyinBQIr0DBF6TG1zXENUip9v9/AA)

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoMzc10EErpEjfQUNZTS04Mz3PQVlTzUHLJ7WkJLXIrzQ3KbUIpCyvREHfIV3foVoJrEdJRykjMQ9IOgZ7A0mP1JycfIXw/KKcFAivQMEXpMbXNcQ1SKn2/38A) while still working with the original input specification.  ([34 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6AoMzc10EErpEjfQcMntaQktcivNDcptchBWU3NME5ZUw2kJK9EQd8h3UHLOSOxKDEZqKZY36FaCaxXSUcpIzEPSDoGewNJj9ScnHyF8PyinBQIr8AXpMTXNcQ1SKn2/38A) taking a list of characters with the new restriction that input is wholly alphabetic)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 77 bytes

```
\W|\d|_

$
¶$`
\G.
1
T`L`l
[t-z]
55$&
[j-z]
55$&
T`_l`ddd
.
$*
A`^(..+)\1+$
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPya8JialJp6LS4Xr0DaVBK4Ydz0uQ66QBJ@EHK7oEt2qWC5TUxU1rugsODMkIT4nISUlhUuPS0WLyzEhTkNPT1szxlAbZML//wFFmbmpXBmJeVyOwd5cHqk5OfkK4flFOSkgdoGCbyqXr2uIaxAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\W|\d|_
```

Delete anything that isn't a letter.

```
$
¶$`
```

Duplicate the letters.

```
\G.
1
```

Replace the letters on the first line with `1`s, thus taking the length in unary.

```
T`L`l
```

Convert the remaining letters to lower case.

```
[t-z]
55$&
[j-z]
55$&
T`_l`ddd
```

Convert them to digits that will sum to their numeric position.

```
.
$*
```

Convert the digits to unary, thus taking their sum.

```
A`^(..+)\1+$
```

Delete any composite values.

```
¶
```

Check that both values are still present.

Comment: I have to say, I'm consistently surprised at just how powerful Retina can be, given the basic idea of "what if regex was a language?"

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>86</s> <s>78</s> 87 bytes

Saved 8 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!
Added 9 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder).

```python
lambda s:~-len(s)*all(n%i for n in(len(s),sum(ord(c)&31for c in s))for i in range(2,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZDfa8IwEIDf@1ccha3JqA/qYCB0MLYO98MpWtiD@hDbVAPxUpIUJ@L@9a6Jcw97GiyQ3Jfv7gK5am83CvtNmSwaybargoEZfHYkR2LoFZOS4IWAUmlAEEhOPjb1lihdkJxe9rsumbdJMJQ6Fo41wzUnvRgpbSw31iQknLAwhnCixZY72DB04W724kI1ru7V1JsHgQLXGVtJXzdKs3TqYMilVA5mo6fX1EGp1Q6/U9XIVz@rjTfZLsVs/9P2rrQs/OMK2Yksl3wyHL@lM3djIQ34R8Vzy4uEZLrmMfzlfGTS/DfQQCckWtS9m@s8Ag/dfkSDX9N0w/ezpHQQQLssJODFXCy9MK1AZf0uiaVe8laef3YurLRAS8ooPNhjCJ1bOJgjHPTcJAlfHiPafAE)

Returns a truthy or falsey value.

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##nZBPawIxEMXv@ymGhXYT2B7UQkFIobRb7B@ruAs9qIe4m9VAnCxJxIr42bebtPbQQw/NIe83780EMs3BbTQO2potWsW3q4qDHXKlCF5IqLUBBIlECSSWpna3JdpUpKSXg54Pyy4ES6ln6dlwXAvST5HS1gnrLCPx1MitiFOINxy93OUvXppJc69nwXmQKHFd8JUKfeOsyGYeRkIp7SEfP71mHmqj9/gdNePQ/aw3wSn2GRaHn7F3bVQVHtfIv8gJJaajyVuWxzQSH40onagYKcxOpPD3/ciV/bfQyDCSLHb9m@sygQC9QUKjX1vzSw47o3QYQXccMAjGXC6DYTujJo6GQnTF@RPnhsZIdKRO4qM7xXB1C0d7gqOZW8bE8pTQ9hM) as a single function.

Comment: @ovs Couldn't believe two `lambda`s were better than one - thanks! :D

Comment: I think this fails when the string is of length 1 (1 is not a prime number).

Comment: @RobinRyder Fixed - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
ḷạ-₉₆ᵐ+ṗ&lṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f7hj@8NdC3UfNXU@amoDCmg/3DldLQdI/P8frRRQlJmbqqSjlJGYByQdg72BZIF/gXN@EIjvkpmXmZcekpiUA1Lj6xriGgSkPVJzcvKBdHBuJlg8rSi/PA8iXuALEvDKzwDxQ8pd80IqYRrC84tyUkBm5uclghklqTmpAR7@fq7BIJuB2Fkp9j8A)

#### How it works

```
ḷạ-₉₆ᵐ+ṗ&lṗ (is the implicit input)
ḷ           to lowercase
 ạ          to list of char codes
  -₉₆ᵐ      minus 96 (so 'a' -> 1)
      +     summed
       ṗ    prime?
        &l  and is the input's length
          ṗ prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Êj ©Uu ¬mc xaI j
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ymogqVV1IKxtYyB4YUkgag&input=IlByaW1lIg)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 69 bytes

```scala
| =>p(|size)&p(|map(_&95-64)sum)
def p(n:Int)=(2 to n/2)forall(n%_>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBa8JAEAXge37FElBmQLFIKxjcgPZiEWkxP0BWnWhkMztmt1Ja@9vjCnrx8t47fDy/Nda0bnOkbVBLU7Gin0C882oq8pecjVVlVoSm4r3OZ85ZMqzbi9K5wMVXv4TdOGojsO6O3/qjV/TfNSY7KpUAZx8cUMNQBad4MMTSNcZa4M46f8H2hgL4@z1qiRUsQwkeMUkiBj/pF3SC9Kupakp76cFwzGmxiCmf8u5WnCLGkyc/J2tdNLFlSQ/y314B)

Answer (score 2):

## C - <s>119</s> <s>108 99</s> 98  bytes    (gcc)

@ceilingcat saved another byte!

```
b,t,e;p(c){for(;--e&&c%e;);c=e==1;}a(char*a){t=0;for(e=b=strlen(a);b;)t+=a[--b]%32;t=p(e)*p(e=t);}
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##Xc6xboMwEMbxnac4URHZKVSmHa/uM3RPMhhzJJacA9nHhHh2Ct3a5Yaf7i99vrl7v21dLTXhpLxehjEpbBo6nXxFqNFbsrbF1Sn/cOns9CLW4PFFtrNZUiRWTmOHWl6tuzRNd6s@3lHspEif92NF47q9BPZx7gk@s/RhfHt8FX8ohu6/pcD3w4rAAk8XWOliKQCOIRD40hpjbrhD9o4HUGWVyzqwPmjaYxlUKZQFEuU5ClQ9gOJRCForaSYwdnAxk77ylcsanNrj3zqRzInBYLFu3yk86Qc)

previously

Many thanks to @DominicvanEssen and @ceilingcat for saving 20 bytes! - and particularly to Dominic for fixing error on n=1 (non-prime)

```
b,t,e;p(c){for(b=c;--b&&c%b;);c=b==1;}a(char*a){t=0;for(e=b=strlen(a);b;)t+=a[--b]%32;t=p(e)*p(t);}
```

first attempt below 119 bytes

```
a(char*a){int t=0,d=strlen(a),e=d;while(d)t+=a[--d]%32;return p(e)*p(t);}
p(int c){int b=c;while(--b&&c%b);return b<2;}
```

In fact can save 3 bytes by using `while(c%--b)` in the second routine, but this fails for the case of p(1) e.g. 'a'. or other single characters.

[try it online](https://tio.run/##XY89bsMwDIV3nYJw4UBy7UJJR0W9SJJBf44FKIwhyegQ@Oyu7KRDuxDkB77HR9NdjVnePJowWQfHlK2/fwxf5A8KXv9n0eN1ZcRjBkXNoCI0TGzjSEst/TbclEfKyIMAbEseT3vO@UUUkIzCHmhVp6r1yFY0FuPc0yq7lCG6NIUMtQWgeM8O9jLHyQGXvQrJsTOesWrL@SLe1NHlKSJwQeblGapR7LHGyJK3VpbcwSFVrHXSiu/BB0cty@9SnbrOXurPg3hZjNSxZqTljZls/4B5GmlpXsKu07udqTX71ejjQczLskZPPw)

Comment: I'm afraid this returns ```1``` (true) for the single-character strings "a", "b" and "c".

Comment: Fixed (I think) for [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY9NboQwDIX3OYVFxSihUIV2maZn6H5mFvkxQ6RMBiVBXSDOTgPtpt1Yfp/87GfT3YzZnlwwfrYI7ylb93gZP8gf5J3@z6ILt50RFzIoakYVoWHikBMttfSHuCsXKCMLATiGXDj3nPOrKCAZFQagVZ2q1gW2o6kszgOtMqYMEdPsM9QWgIZHRuhljjMCl4PyCdklXELVlvPFfLgj5jkG4IKs20@oRrFlj5Elb60suT0GqliL0oqv0XmkluVnqc5dZ6/126vIcqLImomWD1aixfEMGLZoaX4dXadPJ1NrJozUUvZi3bbP6O74DQ)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen - ah rats - missed the bits about 1 above.. many thanks for fixing - and saving 10 bytes

Comment: @ceilingcat- I stare and stare and then you shave off another nearly ten bytes :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>27</sup> <sup>22</sup> 18 bytes

```
1*/@p:#,1#.32|3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1NC4JAEAbgu79iKGjpa9OCDkKQ2UZfZqjQMazWNLbdRYoI@u8W1KGxDnOYZ96ZORUVShIY2ECgBSbYr2pTcIPlpLAanaG2qy2rSnvdR692tYu6sRpR@BpYzW7/4QidxtvTtpZRw@D7VIEFA0iArPPszAmiNJYYnHCBQfvaVUEpNc5kJo9RvBOlex6LWPAh801TLoTCFHqzJcOU5Oomfxa1x7HNVVpKRTcmo/uflxuViwP2sZJx2S5c8PXUX7EQu4NblxRP)

*-5 bytes thanks to xash*

*-4 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen*

- `32|3&u:` Turn each letter into its index by first converting to its ascii number, the modding by 32.
- `1#.` Sum.
- `#,` Prepend list length.
- `1...p:` Are each of those two numbers prime?
- `*/@` Multiply them together -- are they all prime?

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1NC8IwDAbg@35FULD4VZ2Kh4HgnBW/prINPMrUzk1qW4YigvjXp6AHMz3kkCdvkmNWoCSCngUEatAE61V1Co43H2VmpdHXVrFmFmm7de926o926WJlZWMxoPA1NKut7t0WOg43x00poYbBd7ECE3oQAVmlyYkTRHEoMdj@DINeakd5udQwkYk8BOFW5O65LGDeh5pvGnMhFCbfncwZpihVV/mzqF2ObariXCq4Mhnc/rxcq1TssQ@VDPN25oKvxssF87HbuHVI9gQ)

Comment: Are there more `*_j_` string constants than `Alpha`, `Num` and `AlphaNum`? Seem really practical, but they don't appear to be documented in the wiki.

Comment: @xash you can see all of them by first switching into the J locale with `18!:4 <'j'` and then listing all nouns with `4!:1]0`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/39BC0cpEwUY9S50rNTkjX0FHz0TRyjDW4P9/AA "J – Try It Online")  The ones you listed seem to be the only relevant ones for golf.  [More here](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/xmain.htm)

Comment: I have no idea at all how to write 'J', so possibly this is a useless comment, but I don't think you need to subtract 64 before performing MOD 32, since 64 is itself a multiple of 32...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Right you are!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 88 bytes

Returns **0** or **1**.

```javascript
s=>(g=k=>n%--k?g(k):k==1)(Buffer(s).map(c=>x+=n<(n+=c>64&(c&=31)<27&&c),x=n=0)|n)&g(n=x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc9BSwMxEIbhu78iFkxnqNvaKgrS2aKwIEhBWsGLB0M2G@umkyVpZQ/@99ViUatdcM4PH@@8qFcVdVhUq4R9bpqCmkgpWCop5aMkKScWSrwsiYYI1@uiMAEi9peqAk1p3SMeA/dIp@dnErSk0yGORxdSajyuiekE3xilBaYaG@05emf6zlsooHMXFkvTQRSfNxiIVVibg1/qWfG3aVVX89t/qBvjnBcPPrh8oz9UoVzcxyox/UprY9PsPpv97d9h3UfOcmuEVtHELu6ZeMpmh5PtSku2@vlae4/addux5h0)

#### Commented

**Helper function**

```javascript
g = k =>                   // g is a helper function testing if n is prime
  n % --k ?                //   decrement k; if it does not divide n:
    g(k)                   //     do recursive calls until it does
  :                        //   else:
    k == 1                 //     test whether k = 1
```

**Main function**

```javascript
s =>                       // s = input string
  g(                       // test if the 'sum of the letters' is prime
    Buffer(s).map(c =>     //   for each ASCII code c in s:
      x +=                 //     increment x if ...
        n < (              //       ... n is less than ...
          n +=             //         ... the new value of n:
            c > 64 &       //           if c is greater than 64
            (c &= 31) < 27 //           and c mod 32 is less than 27:
            && c           //             add c mod 32 to n
        ),                 //
      x = n = 0            //     start with x = n = 0
    ) | n                  //   end of map(); yield n
  )                        // end of the first call to g
  & g(n = x)               // 2nd call to g with the 'length' x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
uÇ64-Op¹gp&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/9HC7mYmuf8GhnekFav//BxRl5qYCAA)

Bytes removed due to lack of input restrictions

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 78 bytes

```
: d ( s -- ? ) dup [ length ] dip >lower [ 96 - ] map sum [ prime? ] bi@ and ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BTsMwEETv/YpRTnBIj0ikEgXRiAZIWjWpOFQc3NhtLBzb2I6iCvHtYZOKy8zO03q9e2J1MG7Yl1nxkoD5Wkp8CaeFQstCM8ncOtkKDy@@O6FrqqwTIVwI64DFLCsSrEx3VCLejp3xh3HcDwk4buARx1jiFryzOEAJfaaxn@DS4kGZXjii93eIibXMwnctgenHJaGjfATTHIvhB9E0PULUME36VL6R2o19Nrsxr6SW@lwx2oNSnlbpjnwtlDLkZZ69p@QnZ3p95TYfG19NM@aqT3V1@X9AFyg@zjSaTUUQSmzXmyItI/zODnTadd358Ac)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 52 bytes

Uses the prime identification regex from [@Abigail's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210743/72767)

```perl
$_.=$".1x s/./1x(31&ord$&)/ge;$_=!/\b((11+)\2+|1)\b/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXs9WRUnPsEKhWF9P37BCw9hQLb8oRUVNUz891Vol3lZRPyZJQ8PQUFszxki7xlAzJkn/v7VKrq2B9X9HRy5nroCizNxUrozEPC7HYG8uj9ScnHyF8PyinBQQu8A3lcvXNcQ1CCLxL7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dghwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>50</s> <s>55</s> 50 bytes

```
->s{[s.size,s.upcase.sum-64*s.size].all? &:prime?}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFbb4IwFH4/v6LhYa4LElGEaaJm2Vh2cxol2YPzAWdVklq6FmLcst/OCqwR3Fu/y@m5fCJdHbPBimwjBlMR7QlqDlEgUoIuuyZybQy7kJ24jonaHQw38@ca11E@PuG38azi9UzU8zDcRSxi2yBc0crftl2KYz/wZ/9awgOhNM7p@5DKku@2MczHjy/@GX2NYSPiA6vTnlv@wsekIrjK38PwFO@qdsdEjholOPgsONbddsvT07zFgq4rqt1ScttR@8UsrCl5lxaGhFAyfZi8@vPzKlvNMCBsDSDIZxoJgho8P30DNoOsOZTfC2nJ6IuY0kr5RyiJJdN903WuSnpphZSO0EW/KBr9ZDxNJDLUBZPdESVEJrJvAEebhVEkaixLoILUT5Wffv7FpmElLU0VGSkAZZ93lu9y1qg4kS4oYtKgCEeD0yWNZfYL)

+5 bytes due to a misunderstanding of whether arrays could be considered truthy.

-5 bytes thanks to Razetime, using the nice trick of putting the " &:prime?" at the end instead of doing a ".map(&:prime?)" before the ".all?".

Posted separately because Razetime's solution actually didn't sum the alphabet index but simply the ascii ordinals. [It fails for the double prime words "DiningTable" and "METER"](https://tio.run/##ZVFba8IwFH4/vyLkQQ1WsVbtHOgYW4e7OMUW9uBkVIxaqEmXtogb@@1dmi7Yuqec75Kck/OJdH3KRmu6CxjMRXCgqDVGnkgpavQNNDAJ7H125iwDdS0Ct@5zhbOkL5pFd3xR8toGGtoE7gMWsJ3nr8PS26ZZiFPHcxb/WsKEhiHP6Qc/jAu@3yXgTh9fnAv6isBW8COr0vageCWa0pIwkP4hgSe@L9t7BurJUbyjw7xT1W12bD3NGxfhpqSaHSl3e/J/nPkVJe/SIZDQkM4ns1fHvbxlyhlGlG0ABP1MA0FRPcpXX4ftKGuN/e9lw2/HwRet1eSZHkhbyTcGbuBmobQT/hEbSlVlExO8@smiNIkRlrtM9ieU0DiJrzFEaLvEKlu8KoCMVJcySV3@BahhKTdNqbQkgKLPO8t/ddFILUtfUIFpoGLS4LxTvMp@AQ).

Comment: Everything except false and nil is truthy in Ruby. http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/conditionals/nothing_and_truth.html#:~:text=Everything%20except%20false%20and%20nil,hashes%2C%20and%20every%20other%20object.&text=These%20aren't%20nothing%20(%20nil,therefore%2C%20in%20Ruby%2C%20truthy.

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZBdT4MwFIbv@yuaXThrgPA1cCZsMYrZVNwySLxYdlHcYTTpCpaRZRp/O4LECPP2ed5zztvKMj5VXgw7JtBSsj1gdYIjWQK@HCnYMQhKqfhjloJNi6Db8KnHrDqXL/K7bNXJugoeuwTdM8HELqIx7@w2jFYGfuSv/p1EM@A8a/AD5UXLRyZBYTB/9s/wNUGJzI6ij12n3ZIH0BFOnR8T9Jil3bitYLuuEh19EZ36aUN3f9u8ZpJvO9bQa23a9fsyQXumuaITdAAOy9nixQ/Pp4y6gwdii5CE95JJwMO8@fohSrxKndDPNdUK9gEK1cr8jRagFeVedeyrFm80yvkUX9z8DE2/qhwn6wETBcgDTkHCYFN9Aw "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks Razetime! That's a neat trick, I don't understand why that works, but it's good to learn!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
&ṗL¹ṗṁȯ-64ca
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18enJpf/Kip8b/aw53TfQ7tBJIPdzaeWK9rZpKc@P///2ilgKLM3FQlHaWMxDwg6RjsDSQL/Auc84NAfJfMvMy89JDEpByQGl/XENcgIO2RmpOTD6SDfT19XIF0WlF@eR5EvMAXpNArPwPEDyl3zQuphGkIzy/KSQGZmZ@XCGaUpOakBnj4@7kGg2wGYmcgTlGKBQA) Outputs a truthy number if the word is a double prime word, and 0 otherwise.