# Word Length-Sum Multiples

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

A port of my other question: [Double Prime Words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210733/double-prime-words)

Consider a word/string of `n` alphanumeric characters with sum of the characters, `s`, using their numeric position in the alphabet (`a=1, B=2, c=3,` etc.) or numeric value (0,1, 2, 3 - 9). Numeric characters should be taken at individual value. (`66` is two `6` characters for a sum of `12`)

A word is a Length-Sum Multiple if and only if `s` is a multiple of `n`, specifically `s/n` is a positive integer `{1,2,3,4...}`. In the case of `s=0`, and `n={0,00,000,...}`, 0 is a multiple of any `n` but it does not yield a positive integer. Hence an input of `{0,00,000,...}` is False.

Input can be any combination of numbers and upper or lower case alphabetic characters, as there is no numeric difference between `a` or `A`. Handling empty input, `n=s=0`, is not required.

Output is any appropriate logical format related to your language. i.e. True or False, T or F, 1 or 0, positive for truthy and 0 for falsy, etc. Specifying what format your output will appear is highly appreciated, but not required. (Output need not include n or s, but I include them below as demonstration and example)

Winning condition: In as few bytes as possible, write a function that is able to determine if a string is a Length-Sum Multiple.

#### Examples

```
Input -> Output (n,s) 

hello -> False (5, 52) 
MuLtIpLe -> False (8, 108)
Junct10n -> False (8, 83)
Order66 -> False (7, 72)
CodeGolf -> False (8, 67)
SUM -> False (3, 53)
ID -> False (2, 13)

25 -> False (2, 7)
0 -> False (1, 0) 0/1 = 0 which is not a positive integer
10 -> False (2, 1) 

hello2 -> True (6, 54)
5um -> True (3, 39)
length -> True (6, 66)
Order64 -> True (7, 70)
Covid19 -> True (7, 63)
Word -> True (4, 60)
APPLE -> True (5, 50)
lawYER -> True (6, 84)
abc123 -> True (6, 12)
is -> True (2, 28)
television -> True (10, 130)
19 -> True (2, 10)
234 -> True (3, 9)

a -> True (1, 1)
b -> True (1, 2)
C -> True (1, 3)
Z -> True (1, 26)
1 -> True (1, 1)
9 -> True (1, 9)
```

Comment: I left this in the Sandbox for over a week with no responses. I've tried to be as thorough as possible with test cases. Please feel free to suggest any additional cases.

Comment: Sorry I missed this in the sandbox. Overall, a very good challenge! One thing though - I would consider allowing answerers to specify if they want input as whatever, all uppercase, or all lowercase - for most submissions, requiring both will just make them put a "`.lower()`" at the beginning which doesn't add much interesting to solutions. Up to you though - I think there could definitely be some interesting approaches this way too!

Comment: For whatever one opinion is worth, I don't agree with the idea to allow only upper & only lower.

Comment: We can't throw errors when `s` is 0, can we?

Comment: Why is `0` falsey? `0` IS divisible by 1..

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I'm with Dominic van Essen here. I think dealing with the possibility of having both upper and lower case is important.

Comment: @user and Kevin Cruijssen, no errors. 0/1 is 0, which is not a "positive integer" which is detailed in the rules. It is divisible, but not positive, hence it is False.

Comment: "if and only if s is a multiple of n, or more strictly \$s \equiv 0 \mod n\$, or even \$s\div n\$ is a positive integer \${1,2,3,4...}\$" These three contradict each other for \$s = 0\$

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I don't see a contradiction. Looking at online forum discussions, 0 is indeed a multiple of every number, but in order to add depth to the challenge, I added the definition that a multiple needs to be a positive integer. 0 may satisfy one of the definitions, but not both.

Comment: @Sumner18 The contradiction is in "s is a multiple of n" and "more strictly `s mod n == 0`" compared with "s/n is a positive integer". The first two are true for \$s=0\$ and the third isn't. I'd recommend removing the first two and just use the third, which is rigorous enough to work by itself

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've eliminated the definition that `s mod n == 0` as this is encompassed by the second definition that `s\n` is a positive integer `{1,2,3,...}`, except in the edge case of 0. My goal was to imply that 0 is a pseudo-empty input. I can't make the challenge too easy.

Comment: Also didn't think `"Sum"` sums to \$39\$, shouldn't it be \$53\$ as `"SUM"` now is?

Comment: @Noodle9 Notice that it isn't `Sum` but `5um` so `S+u+m = 19+21+13 = 53` but `5+u+m = 5+21+13 = 39` It's a 5 (five) not an S.

Comment: My bad, see where you too got confused now.

Comment: Can the ouput be more than two possible values? For example, positive for truthy, 0 for falsy

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll allow it

Comment: @Sumner18 Thanks for clarifying. You should include that information into the challenge text then

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
þIáÇ32%«ODXgÖ*Ā
```

Input as a list of characters.

-1 byte implicitly thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8D7PwwsPtxsbqR5a7e8SkX54mtaRhv//o5UylHSUUoE4B4rzgdhIKRYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWwS@j/w/siDi883G5spHpotb9LRPrhaVpHGv7r/I9WykjNyclX0lHyLfUp8SzwSQUyvUrzkksMDfKATP@ilNQiMzMgyzk/JdU9PycNyAwO9QWSni5AwsgUSBgAsSGIMIAQYApsrhGQYVqaCyRzUvPSSzLgJpqATSzLTDG0BLLC84tSgJRjQICPK0htYnmkaxCQkZiUbGhkDGRkFgOJktSc1LLM4sx8kMPA@oyMQeYkAnESyDwgjgJJAbGlUiwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
þ                # Only leave the digits of the (implicit) input-list
 Iá              # Push the input-list again, and only leave its letters
   Ç             # Convert each letter to its codepoint integer
    32%          # Take modulo-32 on each codepoint
       «         # Merge it to the list of digits
        O        # Sum this list
         D       # Duplicate this sum
          Ig     # Push the input-list again, and pop and push its length
            Ö    # Check if the sum is divisible by this length
             *   # Multiply it by the duplicated sum
              Ā  # And check that this is NOT 0
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

3 bytes (`D*Ā`) are used for edge-cases `0`/`00`/`000`/etc.

Comment: I had [`þSDŠKÇžw%«ODIgÖ*Ā`](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//8O@U0TFoEvDh8W@dyXCq09ESWfDlirEgP//Q292aWQxOQ) - only one byte longer :).

Comment: @ovs Nice. I was actually just looking for some alternatives and found another 16-byter: [`Asálk>®þ«OD®gÖ*Ā`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fsfjwwpxsO8/D@w6t9nfxTD88TetIw///0UrOSjpK@UBcBsSZQJwCxIZAbKkUCwA). No 15-byter yet, although I have the feeling it's possible.

Comment: @ovs Actually, I think your approach opens up a 15-byter like this: [`þIáÇžw%«ODIgÖ*Ā`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWwS@j/w/siDi883H50X7nqodX@LhHph6dpHWn4r/M/WikjNScnX0lHybfUp8SzwCcVyPQqzUsuMTTIAzL9i1JSi8zMgCzn/JRU9/ycNCAzONQXSHq6AAkjUyBhAMSGIMIAQoApsLlGQIZpaS6QzEnNSy/JgJtoAjaxLDPF0BLICs8vSgFSjgEBPq4gtYnlka5BQEZiUrKhkTGQkVkMJEpSc1LLMosz80EOA@szMgaZkwjESSDzgDgKJAXElkqxAA), so thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>73</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>63</s></sup> 61 bytes

Saved <s>a</s> 3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
n;u;f(char*s){for(n=u=0;*s;++n)u+=*s&15+*s++/64*16;u*=u%n<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJta9swEP6eX6EaMvxWatmxGqN6MLowWlJaNsbYljBcW24MrhwsuwsN@e2p7uSlK2u/zJyfu5Pu5fH58uO7PN/vJe95aeerrHWVsy2b1pZpnwbcVdzzpNN7qave0dhzleedsIlLGe/dtB/LM8p3@0p25D6rpO2MtiOiHyxEOqG6X@rnkqRka61EXTeWT6yrft5drOcC7Mte5h0NJNjXbSFaxsA8bwrxqalLsL98vQJ18REwjAEDAIqIVUOw4v4eVC3kXbd6rjcx9R6qgiZgfmvaAvSHm5v5DBOy399nn8HKbnMaRmBVCrATtXioVNUgPZMeRlgwA7jF0gA/MAAgsXYcJwAjIWYC0kwg9skU5RQx8kmIQhEZnjC81TLxSYwuMzEBqgijX8i/7fqhHaZBR511Ch102SjRhxF2CDA/nphDBp31EQMSWsf6neo7ChynkBQYFskfwsCfoZO84CA2a5F3ojAsAmz0ltD/k6GfWbJ22K/FZhYuNsm5fnFJ/vIj@CmYoheb2MCzkoXY6LyAD@YZUdWjaErbLK1zMrju4HPieRjpELPizwyUrjOsOkYs@SFgGIkOOIzl9ZBMhxwdlbZudLhZt/qutK2xIsfvybggY7WAVVQ@yXz93VmaiuUQvxvt9k8)

Inputs a string and returns a truthy if it's a Length-Sum Multiple or a falsey otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒlO%48Sȯ.%L
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields zero (falsey) if the string is a *length-sum-multiple* or a non-zero number (truthy) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opBx/VROL4BPr9VR9/v//r@RflJJaZGaiBAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opBx/VROL4BPr9VR9/j9qmJOXX5D6qGEukFWZWqAIZB1ut3/UtAaI3P//j45WygDqy1fSUVDyLfUp8SzwSQWxvUrzkksMDfJAbP@ilNQiMzMQ0zk/JdU9PycNxA4O9QVRni4g0sgURBqACEMDpVguHai5RiAR09JcEJWTmpdekoEw0QRiYllmiqEliBmeX5QCoh0DAnxcwRoSyyNdg0CsxKRkQyNjECuzGESWpOaklmUWZ@aDHQjRbmQMNjARRCSBjQYRUWAFIMJSKTYWAA).

#### How?

```
ŒlO%48Sȯ.%L - Link: list of characters, w  e.g. "ID"       "10"     "19"     "0...0"
Œl          - lower-case (w)                    "id"       "10"     "19"     "0...0"
  O         - ordinals                          [105,100]  [49,48]  [49,57]  [48,...,48]
    48      - forty-eight                       48         48       48       48
   %        - modulo                            [9,4]      [1,0]    [1,9]    [0,...,0]
      S     - sum                               13         1        10       0
        .   - a half                            0.5        0.5      0.5      0.5
       ȯ    - logical OR                        13         1        10       0.5
         L  - length (w)                        2          2        2        length(w)
        %   - modulo                            1          1        0        0.5
                                               (nope       nope     yep!     nope)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>29</sup> 24 bytes

```
#(|=0=])1#.48|64|96|3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc9Na4MwAMbxez9FmLCs0IlRK1XwMFw3OpRJSykt9OBLnI7MDF@6i9/dCuuhTw45/H@IefI9Pui0IL5HKFkQg3jTedZJsA3fRu1p8A3/PGeabq8Gxx5cZ7Aee2@cz2Y8K@X0qU8KQksuhKRAUR92m9@Qo370ddYxo0b9bHLeOA5iIHP@LkWButtHCJtXbHOJbWCyqW/b2d12k4It@x8EweuvrkT7X20jBvJS5cxFPMgmR3mJ43CtXJH8HddbtCTNmGmhVS12xwW/VG0la3R1hGkpUxPMVHkI5kn5OeZ01XgF)

*-5 bytes thanks to xash*

Inspired by [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211431/15469) -- be sure to upvote him.

- `3&u:` turns the string into ascii codes
- `96|` mods the lowercase letters into the range 1-26
- `64|` mods the uppercase letters into the range 1-26
- `48|` mods the digits into the range 0-9
- `1#.` sum of all those converted digits
- `#` (on the far left) length of string
- `(|=0=])` First we check if the sum is zero `0=]` -- this will return `1` when it is and `0` otherwise.  Then we check if sum mod the length `|` is equal to *that*.  Thus for the entire phrase to return true it must be the case that the sum is *both* evenly divisible its length and nonzero.

*Why can't you just use a single 32 mod instead of doing a 96 followed by a 64?*

With 32, you'd be affecting the values 0-9 as well. With 96/64, you fix the letters without touching the digits, and now, since the letters are all 26 and under, when you fix the digits the already-fixed letters are unaffected.

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##XdBdT4MwFAbge37FiUvWERFbPpqNyIXiNDNMlxljdFkMgyIYpIbBvGn868jiYna46MX7tDl924/2xCQp@B4QMICC160zE4JleNMORsqn/lpnA9MZK@6oCVf2sPFaXbu/MoH6A/XGTrvdlWc4Y7AttfJG63Pz52LIqd4Jd439eU0TcSYhBfJQJaLiDjkIBX@vmSgKSRDNm7CefYUC611TxjWjJda/oRxjIBNxK4sU6@PTHMPsGmfLxZniyLp86M6OulsEmdt8YihE@V5n2P6/4hgDucsTNsH4LKsEy@ViEU57V0TfL9MltmgTM8vGlm9xrkUhdvk2lyX2fgnL7lWNcNz0HoLja284jt1V7S8)

Comment: Excellent.  That added enough cleverness to be worthy of explanation :)

Comment: Based on the explanation, I would have guessed that one could replace both ```64|``` and ```96|``` with ```32|```, but that doesn't seem to be the case when I try...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen With 32, you'd be affecting the values 0-9 as well.  With 96/64, you fix the letters without touching the digits, and now, since the letters are all 26 and under, when you fix the digits the already-fixed letters are unaffected.

Comment: Got it!  It's right-to-left mods of the same number, right?  Sorry for not having any clue about J syntax...

Comment: Exactly.  J evals from right to left always.  So eg `2*3+1` is 8, not 7.  One of Iverson's main reasons for inventing APL was his frustration with unnecessary complexity of "order of operations."

Comment: I love it!  ...and, I've immediately stolen that trick to save 1 byte in my R answer.  Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>63</s> <s>62</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

*Edit: saved 1 byte thanks to Jonah*

```r
function(s)!sum(i<-utf8ToInt(s)%%96%%64%%48)%%nchar(s)&i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZRdS8MwFIbv/RXHSaWFDpO2y1pQQfxiMnHoRBRhdF1mA1k62nT@/JkiXrTpGV42fZ7Tk5w3LfeSqy@dL6p6s9jUUout5Bf7da0yLQrlVt6xeeOK82Gt1/G8mCht1hwnYY7DIseJYvOgsjwtzfKp6KvmDnIuZTHw4ASGl3CXyoqDO/JhFHhw1Cs81lM92U55x4l9oCT2@p2HpmVKlO3EIaI8lSteMtYxxj6MA8S4Llb8vpBr@yNsjCgvr48dOvQhTBB6ctOBA7NnrP9gZMNYG6SDUh@IB@SMwgUQ@M5FloOoQBUaUtgWldBix0Eozb942V@Skp5ezUizVLuDTzOIIzwNwZ86L2tjMpOGCOFH9aYNHzq/30WrOGMHIxC1hSYBBE3ATqxoYgkMG9JbUa7adGRorPzVbDa9bePNTcFwmX6/3z5b242xs0yXGQ1Ci6dY3kXVZs2EA@wCai75TlTmr9F2KGkijO2ge5RNhjA2CCMrCVgQ0k4TTTT7yaVForffIrGhf9g1sQTSfzeaWGTi7X8A)

Output is Truthy list of one-or-more TRUEs, or Falsy list of one-or-more FALSEs.

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, <s>71</s> <s>62</s> 46 bytes

- Fixed answer thanks to [@Mr Redstoner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88701/mr-redstoner)
- Saved 9 bytes thanks to [@Dominic Van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)
- Saved 16 bytes! thanks to [the tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211411/word-length-sum-multiples/211437#comment497885_211437) [@xash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95594/xash) gave on [Jonah's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211437/95792), which Dominic Van Essen suggested.

```scala
s=>{val x=(0/:s)(_+_%96%64%48);x>0&x%s.size<1}
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1frIe3r4R6aJc0ILZoa7bg)

### 32 bytes if zero weren't falsey

```scala
s=>(0/:s)(_+_%96%64%48)%s.size<1
```

[Try it online](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/5I0NvWfqTZqCbrENOeS0jw)

Comment: As far as I can tell yours fails on the "0" test case

Comment: @MrRedstoner Fixed it for 71 bytes :(

Comment: 67 bytes: ```s=>{val x=s.map{x=>if(x.isDigit)x%48 else x%32}.sum;x>0&x%s.size<1}```

Comment: If you 'steal' the amazingly-cunning trick from xash's tip for [Jonah's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211437/95126), you could even get 50 bytes: ```s=>{val x=s.map{x=>x%96%64%48}.sum;x>0&x%s.size<1}```... (at which point you'll be beating me...).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Wow, that's really clever

Answer (score 3):

## [Java](https://www.java.com/en/) <sup><s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s></sup> 64 bytes

```
s->{int u=0;for(int c:s)u+=c%96%64%48;return u>0&u%s.length<1;};
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##lZRta8IwEIA/r7@iCI4WZ7G@MVcVNueGQ5nMDRnih9imNS4mJbk4RPztrk43GMLwvh3J89zlciELsiJFmVKxiD52bJlKBfYiW/MMMO7FRoTApPAejkFghZxobY/7o1eqwd5YlgYCLLR/iGY4J2oyvbqTklMi2klrp4vtDRNgm1YpiKVy9nF4o11TaIX5Rj1fr@ar14GiYJSwTbt0afLa41QkMG/6wTbYndQYgWIi@a0Rt7ISiUfSlK8d7YHsZGe4VYqsHdcNrNTMeGYfk6wki@wlYcI5ZJlMiUq0u7EuLkZrDXTpSQNemm0BF058zJqbU85lzi3k7JhwTXNZ3v@FgelDL@1TjPO0b9AvCYzzrCKq6nWM0pERfZQ8xjijtwEG791j6HINQ5cwsH9CnzPo8rcEypxRoWaWCPrwrhHCYb5VhNGRKxb5DYQxlipC4LfDYb@L6Zl8vndfEAKZhX65ghCYRsBAOV0xnX0kCAl1n@UKZl7kL7u1trsv)

My first ever answer! The "0" test case messed me up, without it I could have had 51, (I wanted to try challenge the C answer, from which I've borrowed the char-to-number conversion). Now pretty much a port of the C answer.

```
s->s.chars().map(c->c%96%64%48).sum()%s.length()<1;
```

Still fairly proud of beating out some of current answers in languages like Python and JavaScript using the 'oh so verbose' Java.

Thanks to @user for a few extra bytes saved

@ceilingcat for a few more

@dominic-van-essen for 2 more using @xash's idea

Comment: @user thanks, I really should have taken a better look at that C submission and realized that myself.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZRtS8MwEIA/219RBkqLLrSdG2i3yZwvKBPFKUPED1mbdplpUpLLZIz99lrdFEQQ79uRPM9dLhcypwvaVCWT8/S14kWpNLjzeo1Y4IJkVibAlSQX2yB2EkGNcSej8QMz4K4cxwAFnrhfRDeZUf38cnCqlGBU9vNeZZr9FZfg2l4QZ0p7H3FybHy730v2vKTbOTwJ28et0I81A6ula/vBnt01RDCZw6wbxuu4@lVnDJrL/LtO1qvL5ISWpVh6hoAa1ucYaE2Xnu/HTmmnora3SRaKp25BufQ2WZ5fqM6Nv3J2dsZLA6wgygIp6y0Q0su2WRszJoRq@PsNN6PCsEad92/hxo7gqhwxjHP90WAYSIxzq1OmOx2MMlQpu1QiwzjjxxsMfnWGoaM2hg4wcPiL/s@go08JtP1HhbYtEPTmXSOEzXwPEcZQLXgaHiGMidIpAh/c3Y3OMT3Tt6fze4RAp0kYtRACNwgYmGALbuqPBCGh7jNqYeZFf7JrZ129Aw) if you use an array

Comment: A shame about loosing Stream and making it pretty much a port of the C answer, but at least the fails-on-"0" is staying a Stream because I can't find a way to apply the same improvement without making it worse.

Comment: Very nice answer! [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZRta8IwEIA/r7@iCI4WZ7G@MVcVNueGQ5nMDRnih9imNS4mJbk4RPztrk43GMLwvh3J89zlciELsiJFmVKxiD52bJlKBfYiW/MMMO7FRoTApPAejkFghZxobY/7o1eqwd5YlgYCLLR/iGY4J2oyvbqTklMi2klrp4vtDRNgm1YpiKVy9nF4o11TaIX5Rj1fr@ar14GiYJSwTbt0afLa41QkMG/6wTbYndQYgWIi@a0Rt7ISiUfSlK8d7YHsZGe4VYqsHdcNrNTMeGYfk6wki@wlYcI5ZJlMiUq0u7EuLkZrDXTpSQNemm0BF058zJqbU85lzi3k7JhwTXNZ3v@FgelDL@1TjPO0b9AvCYzzrCKq6nWM0pERfZQ8xjijtwEG791j6HINQ5cwsH9CnzPo8rcEypxRoWaWCPrwrhHCYb5VhNGRKxb5DYQxlipC4LfDYb@L6Zl8vndfEAKZhX65ghCYRsBAOV0xnX0kCAl1n@UKZl7kL7u1trsv) if you steal xash's MOD tip for Jonah's answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda s:(sum(ord(c)%48for c in s.lower())or.5)%len(s)
```

An unnamed function accepting a string which returns zero (falsey) if the string is a length-sum-multiple or a non-zero number (truthy) if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQq7gRZjZu@hBBZ@gCbSqVBJ2R0YhOb73ty2@9mLrml63FPR12V2WGcidgsXCi7ifPok4VSBUT@XECiCxmQB0dQcGWJVAFD4HyXf/Etop1MvYf)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##TVDvS8MwEP3uX3EGBgmM0nbrcAM/iA6ZbDgUEcUv/XG1kTQpSbqxv772MkXz4d3jcvd497qTb4yeDfX1x6DytqhycCvu@pYbW/FSTOZXtbFQgtTgImWOaLkQxkaZmCjU3ImB/j0672iGX8D4OGtQKcOmwHb91m@6LRJ/6HXpk1gTf7QV2sWC6K2p8N6omvjzy47K5o4wzQhjgiRmYvpfO6Vu1rdURiOfvvlTnZ9VD7JKlkRfx1uo3uz323VYyI9v6ydieVEm6YyYdIQeFR6kkyaYPK@nsyCYExRBmuA9DBAsyZpYBXedldpzBiz6MlJzpk2HDGQNNaeMBKByCOyE3SWD3@QouJCgEMPPBd8).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda d:1>(x:=sum(int(c,36)-9*(c>'9')for c in d))%len(d)<x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBRS8MwEMff@ynyIklkg7Xdih1uIDpk0uFQRHTuoWvSLZA2JU3nZOyz17uAPtzld/dP/sml@XEHU8c3je1LMiNfvc6rnciJmIZzdprO2q5iqnasGMQJH6bXrJjTlPLSWFIQVRPB@ZWWNRP89tQ72boWXDYbepBaGzqgqy5zyyaTgE9dXbhwVAM@WyFtkgDdGyEfjS4BX99WkJcPdDvY0GgCPIIIR772fhHUk66CDFfu3eHfaeydjkqEKdC7sQKWu/U6W@De/Ptj8QKQ74owigFUC8lJLY@qVQYf5M9F8djflQPv0BHiE0WIlG63QYBj763pGhzdTzsNCMEuFtj0KjYJaSx@XEnPqF3IcE7OJUPmF8qDP533vw)

Comment: is this "x:=" an assignment inside an expression? That's rather new isn't it?

Comment: @Teck-freak yes it was introduced in version 3.8 and is called [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). The *walrus operator* is quite handy for golfing.

Comment: yes, I even played around a bit when it was introduced. I completely forgot about it, as I'm mainly doing addons in 2.7 and 3.4 and maybe 3.7  Nice idea going with a base36 int by the way.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
≔ΣＥ↧θ﹪℅ι⁴⁸η∧η¬﹪ηＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsMwDET3fkVGGdKtQyFT9qQttD8gbBELXKm1nfTzFQd6y/GOx/mI2Ssms7EUXgSe6xtm/MCkP8oeC8HX9d2sYU0K9xxYMAG36XJ1rlV0w@mRWSqMEiD23U0r/PVGE8lSY/s4Mpi9KNHGhVXsvKUd) Link is to verbose version of code. Output is a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a multiple, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
≔ΣＥ↧θ﹪℅ι⁴⁸η
```

Convert the string to lower case, take the code points of all the characters, reduce them modulo 48, then take the sum.

```
∧η¬﹪ηＬθ
```

Check that the sum is a non-zero multiple of the length of the string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-plF`, 32 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to [@Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul)!

```perl
$s+=ord(lc)%48for@F;$_&&=1>$s%@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3hC8FAHMbx98/fsYmkdrPJEhEmmogk3mi2w@pnt@5uk3/eWfL6@X56Ci7JN8@3pQbGUu2hkGmTkpbt9W9CjsOBdWk0hmxkKXscGvPgRALrMtLLIuJYlXmimZNjI1Muez1MRcoXgm7YH9ZYzuD6cMAc/JwLv3yCeH7Xj7/walFlKQtwrI8x2W6jOSh@neY7xNeEuV1kCpoTrzKViRx16XY9xLhiijMYgo8odL0o0yko/AI)

Comment: 38 bytes without using sum [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1tywFBAIXh7@d3DJFkZ9Yq5C2saEUkkdIyg62xs83Mkj//zLPJ53NfnUxoGbjnh5iuI6bWa5x4Y0DOHaV5pVry2U3pYdgl53K5R/vElIahcw8hpcIyj@w8iwQWeXq11Eux0lzoVgtjxcVMyRu2uyXmE7AAHqiHr2MI8iekSO/28RPNQrwSTtvYF7cYrdfRFDJ@H6YbxJcrZT4SAyukeCUmUSmKkvlNxLhgjCMo2n8qs8ViXD2T4T8 "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Nice! Much cleaner, thank you! I wasn't happy with it last night, but I didn't have time to go back to it :)

Comment: nice trick to switch to lowercase so that 96%48 is also 0

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> <s>17</s> 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input is an array of characters.

Or [13 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=eMh2IGMgdTQ4w3ZVbA&input=WyIwIl0), without having to special-case `0`.

```
xÈv c u48
©vNÎl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=eMh2IGMgdTQ4Cql2Ts5s&input=WyIwIl0)

```
;x@ÒBbXu)ªX\n©vNÎl     :Implicit input of character array U
 x                     :Reduce by addition
  @                    :After passing each X through the following function
   Ò                   :  Negate the bitwise NOT of
;   B                  :  Uppercase alphabet
     b                 :  0-based index of
      Xu               :    Uppercase X
        )              :  End indexing
         ªX            :  Logical OR with X, which gets coerced to an integer
           \n          :Reassign to U
             ©         :Logical AND with
              v        :  Is divisible by
               N       :  Array of all inputs
                Î      :  First element (i.e., the original U)
                 l     :  Length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>101</s> 96 bytes

```python
def f(s):x=sum([i-[48,96][i>96]for i in map(ord,s.lower())]);return not(x%len(s))and x//len(s)>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDbasMwDIbv8xS6GbYhXZP0wNrRwtjK6GhZ2RhjC7lIG6c1pHawnR4offZM9tguJH@S7F@y6rPdKdlr24KXUFLDxqeJafY0FZ20fxeOhlkqpuhLpUGAkLDPa6p0EZrbSh25poxl7F5z22gJUll6uqm4RB2WywJO3e5vNI1ay401MIE0JTteVYqEZNks7LxecMSXRm5sHEnEV11wPRwiPaqCP6uqRHz/WKKfP5EsTEkyQI7Q4sjHXi/BeNDs0WPLrd39K/W90kEU8QjpE4fH42G1Wszc3fz4NXtDyNebOOkhCIPO8oofhBHKDeTfJb2@75Ujr50i2rcroo1IlgWBW9FWq6Z2a/K/HQcALusCl/RVlwSotZCWluTialfoTOFSUsfsSljwV2ftDw)

Comment: You can replace your ternery construct "-96if i>96else i-48" with "-[48,96][i>96]" which saves you 5 bytes (boolean as index).

Comment: You can return "not x%len(s)" The brackets fall away (operation-order) and the "and"-part isn't needed as the only case where it is 0 is for empty strings, or if we have rest. empty strings need not be checked and rests are already indicating a False => saves 16 Bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
ØWiⱮ_³e€ØD¤%26Sµ;ọ³L¤$Ȧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATYAyf9qZWxsef//w5hXaeKxrl/Cs2XigqzDmETCpCUyNlPCtTvhu43Cs0zCpCTIpv///0NvdmlkMTk)

Golfed 1 byte and also made the program actually work (third time's a charm? it was still broken)

### Explanation

```
ØWiⱮ_³e€ØD¤%26Sµ;ọ³L¤$Ȧ  Main Link
   Ɱ                     For each character in the input
  i                      find its index in
ØW                       "ABC...XYZabc...xyz0123456789_"
    _                    and subtract from each element
     ³e€ØD¤              the corresponding value, which is
     ³                   if the original character
      e€                 is a member of
        ØD               the digits (this is to fix the one-off offset of the digits)
                         (the above nilad gets a list of 0 and 1 for if each character is a digit, and since Jelly's subtraction `_` is vectorized, this works as subtracting the corresponding element)
           %26           modulo 26
              Sµ         take the sum; begin a new link with this value
                ;    $   append
                 ọ       the number of times the sum is divisible by (just plain "divisible by?" has the arguments in the opposite order which would take 1 extra byte to flip)
                  ³L¤    the length of the input
                      Ȧ  any and all - are both values truthy; that is, is the sum divisible and non-zero?
```

Comment: [This fails for `0`](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xZJ1TyvigbQkPDYwVCTCpl82NFPCtTvhu43Cs0zCpCTIpv///zA), an irritating corner case

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing i thought i fixed that lol??? well, thanks for pointing that out, i managed to golf 0 bytes with a different approach but it did fix the problem!

Comment: Well, it's a better answer than mine (yours actually works :P), very nice :D. Interesting that you used `ØW` (my original approach used `ØB`)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yeah my first try used that and I think I just ended up copy-pasting a different one when I retried with this approach lol

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>54</s>  53 bytes

Returns **0** or **1**.

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>t+=++k&&c%96%64%48,k=t=0)|t%k<!!t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdLvT4JAGAfw9/0V6obCLAVEFlu4lWmz4XL9WCvrxQmHEifHuIPW1v9ONCpB7wJess@@99x9nzeQAGJHXkhPAuzA1DVTYo4uYteFkUik3haEom2OaNfsdv122xYMXdA1QTs99k1qytInFfyzZpOmNg4IRrCH8FrsLKcAkY/XjnRU/O2KrQ1ECLckqZF//X7jW8J9No8tOgst@CN57DoObKrIQQW7iRwY6frvsTw2zu5/hZFbkXb3MN9dgM9ml0XFZeqwFpNLissUmZ1Wcp2XYHkfxXTDLUj9S8kSMnpwzjDe7r0BSyEYrOmmKitvRyu0w1JjnHiOYlSoRxw5hcE46nyxsCalJWROD96fJrdV04OVraiDKuWR/V5YikIEE494OF9ojto9wn9Z6kCr0RA4WCuWWtVS41rquZZSaimDqdIv)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 & Python 3 -- 69 Bytes

```
lambda a:0==sum(ord(s.upper())-[64,48][s.isdigit()]for s in a)%len(a)
```

Assuming the input as string on variable a, one can get down to 60 Bytes

```
0==sum(ord(s.upper())-[64,48][s.isdigit()]for s in a)%len(a)
```

Comment: Hello, based on [site consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), input cannot be taken as a variable. You could wrap your program into a function/lambda and it would be valid. Also, your program has to either output the value or return it from a function, it cannot be a single expression that evaluates to the answer.

Comment: Hello @HyperNeutrino I fail to see how a single expression is not applicable, but yes, I'll modify it into a lambda. (it is my fift golf and the first in over 2 years.)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 107 bytes

```javascript
a=>(b=a.toLowerCase().split('').reduce((c,d)=>c+(+(isNaN(d)?d.charCodeAt(0)-96:d)),0)/a.length,!(b?b%1:!b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdJdT8IwGAXge3/FJDG0AeY2hUQSIEbRYPAjfsToXde@QLWsy9qh/nrkM0ZfTHt/ntPk9H1jM2Z4IXPbMLkUUEx19g5f81FnzjpdknZYaPVQf0BxxgwQGppcSUuqVRoWIEoOhPC6oJ0ur5EakeaG3RBBeyLkE1acaQGnlkS0cdJqC0rrET1koYJsbCf1fZL20oO4vZ9SOuc6M1pBqPSYVCaglA4ajW7Q/8yBWxDt4IIpA/XgHkypbDuo1EabXIXSvV/6uhzaQT4Ej4JtFHVclRm3cZR5dGyjqOO2WKzZanlUbJKoYTnfpVYjj4ptFHU8PF178GUK0cG5h1yEEEyabpc0EYs8nouQin1YjN3qeJI/9rEodx5ZgniznLrtIoTg@vrddp3756qO3X4T3HFUMyniE3fBJogKnnUh3HqZQvT07m7Yd9JVCu/GPl769x67rXKIs5THyZGbr3OIS@Om0iBmQcFMGqkzN//J4hv3@K4dP5UcedzJIoTH8tgJodSNUnyNHneI0KsbveINPSZEyGP31ezzbw)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
k48\stGn\~*
```

Output is `0` if the input is length-sum multiple, or a positive number otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9vEIqa4xD0vpk7r/3/1jNScnHx1AA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##PY5LC4JAFIX3/op2A618k8tIEUNJehCJi3xMKY1O6Git@ut2xqDFOfNd7szHNJlg03V6mKu0F36bfpaTm7yPE6koY5woJBpCETxDCtwObSE0tQXuupJ2tg3a8JL6nN2Ah1OEDlyUbqFURFPJQvnJdIzW0KAZbe@i@mvMWTPWpeaAzrwrcazjOPTk3ex18faALC803QDUPUpQRse6r7n8zfxON6QnQ3LpQxK5QhzyBQ).

#### How it works

```
k     % Implicit input. Convert to lowercase
48    % Push 48
\     % Modulus. Each character is first converted to its code-point
s     % Sum. This gives "s"
t     % Duplicate (*)
G     % Push input again
n     % Number of elements. This gives "n"
\     % Modulus
~     % Negate. This gives true if s mod n equals 0, or false otherwise (**)
*     % Multiply (*) and (**)
      % Implicit display. True and false are displayed as 1 and 0 respectively
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 63 bytes

```
^
$.'$*1;
T`L`l
[j-z]
55$&
[t-z]
55$&
T`_l`ddd
\d
$*
^(1+);\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctbD8EwAIbh@@931GlC1jGJuBIWmUwIExGnjhaVamU6En9@RMTde/E@qbBSJ3mhPGD5FqReIg7tIGYRU1hdaq8NfJ8UsbL/jNlOMc451hzEwbZMq5XOmlZJnp@FUgajLLLhLRIYZvpgqasxTrlIWy30DBcDo46YzUcI@/B8uKAuvs6Dn12hhD7Z8080P@IhOW1jYVKO7mQSBVDJcxlMkewP1GtA3mGFEg95l0bjc3qN5hs) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^
$.'$*1;
```

Prefix the input with a unary copy of itself.

```
T`L`l
```

Convert it to lower case.

```
[j-z]
55$&
[t-z]
55$&
T`_l`ddd
```

Convert the letters to digits with the same digital sum.

```
\d
$*
```

Take the digital sum.

```
^(1+);\1+$
```

Check that it is a non-zero multiple of the length.

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 78 bytes

```
%|0/[!843WWP843WWWA/]~[!88WP88WWA/]~[!86WP86WWA/]_1A![1A~M~]%!~!~/P\WA{0:.}?1:
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%7C0%2F%5B!843WWP843WWWA%2F%5D%7E%5B!88WP88WWA%2F%5D%7E%5B!86WP86WWA%2F%5D_1A!%5B1A%7EM%7E%5D%25!%7E!%7E%2FP%5CWA%7B0%3A.%7D%3F1%3A&input=length)

Waiting for answer in 1+...

Uses the modulus method from Jonah's J answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 54 bytes

```
Tr[a=FromDigits/@#/.a_/;a>9:>a-9]~Mod~Tr[1^#]==0<Tr@a&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5dS8MwFIbv/RWlAy@K2o99QJ0dka7KRovFTURHlbM0XQNtI2k6L8T99doTEW@e83By8vLWoEpWg@IU@sII@q3cQXAnRb3kB65am4zsK3i357Dwrxdw6WenROSn4cp9G2VB4NxsJYHzfkOh2aWSN4pYBbHCEiRQxWRLrIiWIiNfZ4ZhmCWrKmFeGGbSxWr1ETP0dddQ5ToN@oPMmZzNUEORs3tRFeibp2QYOmK1xIU3RToIV1Mne2jTrsZRseagyv/MyV9AKI48d318eRYyx3mbpnGkP8HnS/SIBnvqemM03iIVq9iRt1wMNXXMb4I3nuhrxF63RrzqXgjf/J73Pw) Pure function. Takes a list of characters as input and returns `True` or `False` as output. The bulk of the work is done by `FromDigits`, which converts the characters 0-9, A-Z to the numbers 0-35.